# Is the official direction of Stack Overflow now to help educate the next generation of developers?

Tags: discussion, scope, blog

[In glancing at the latest blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/03/28/the-next-ceo-of-stack-overflow/?cb=1), a line jutted out at me as part of the new CEO search:

> One thing I’m very concerned about, as we try to educate the next generation of developers, and, importantly, get more diversity and inclusiveness in that new generation, is what obstacles we’re putting up for people as they try to learn programming. In many ways Stack Overflow’s specific rules for what is permitted and what is not are obstacles, but an even bigger problem is rudeness, snark, or condescension that newcomers often see.

Is our mission then to cater to users looking to *learn* programming?  Are we getting a CEO that will then make that the ultimate objective of Stack Overflow?

Comment: If they do, it's going to alienate the vast majority of their established userbase.

Comment: @fbueckert:  Hell, at a minimum I'm glad we have ***a*** direction.  I got tired of mewling in the dark trying to figure out what direction Stack Overflow was going.  It may not be a direction I *agree* with, but it is ***a*** direction.

Comment: Not yet, we don't.  We're still fumbling around in the dark, waiting to see if SE will actually formalize their direction, and people can actually base their decision off of that, or if they'll just keep it quiet because they know what it'll do to their userbase.  My money's on the latter.

Comment: Fair.  Nothing's official about this yet.  If they did say it officially then yes, that'd probably alienate even more of their established user base. But even then I'm not sure how they actually come out with a "win" on this.  Joel said what he had to to be sure to address the concerns from the rather vocal and sometimes right group of people who think we're being unwelcoming; had he ignored *them*, he'd risk shrinking the potential user base for future Stack Overflow products or services.

Comment: In either way I think this is a rock and a hard place.  I prefer honesty over ambiguity so I'm at least interested in hearing a firm answer one way or another about this.

Comment: Until we get a full throated defense of quality somewhere public, and not in out of the way places like [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45682674#45682674), I have very large doubts.  It's safe to say it where most people won't see it, but will pacify curators enough to keep them engaged for a little bit longer.  But making it public would risk alienating those same new users who *can't* or *won't* meet that quality bar.  Can't have that, now can we?

Comment: That's the open question @fbueckert.  What does it mean for someone to come to Stack Overflow for the sake of learning how to program?

Comment: If we're supposed to teach how to program, then SE has lost it's way, and I want nothing to do with it anymore.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think very many people *can't* meet the quality bar.  Many choose not to spend the effort to do so, many don't even know they're expected to, but while it's a good bit of work, it's work most anyone can do (or learn to do).

Comment: Wording is hard. I interpreted it as: we're a useful resource for education, and answers on Stack Overflow will educate new users on subjects they're unfamiliar with, not as: we're formally going to educate programmers. I agree it's ambiguous, but we can't deny that users do learn here.

Comment: @fbueckert: I learned Lua [asking and answering on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1438+[lua]). And before that I learned Perl by answering questions on Usenet. It's a pretty good way to learn. The sort of self-protective culture you seem to be referring to is a reason I haven't participated in Usenet for, well, as long as SO has been an option. Maybe let's learn for history?

Comment: @ErikA:  May I borrow your interpreter?  I read it as something *completely* opposite of that.  You raise a point about learning being incidental, but that's not what was spelled out or called out.

Comment: @JonEricson - your level of participation on the site was plenty appropriate.  You came with objective questions or provided objective answers and everyone mutually benefited from it.  Had you never mentioned that you used SO to learn Lua, we'd be none the wiser.  I'm not opposed to people using Stack Overflow to learn how to program.  I'm opposed to the mission of Stack Overflow being for us to *teach* them how to program.  There's a difference, even if there's some nuance in verbiage here.

Comment: @JonEricson I've done the same with other languages, but at least I don't read the quote from the question as referring to, "People using SO questions as a source of interesting problems to solve, and who learn about the topic by researching and attempting to solve those problems on their own, and then posting the answers for others to benefit from".  Yes, people do that, but that quote seems to refer more to people asking questions *instead* of researching or trying to solve problems on their own, and asking questions the site (currently) considers low quality as a result.

Comment: @JonEricson Sure.  As long as you can ask good questions, no issue.  But here's the rub: *most don't*.  And SE is encouraging that behaviour in all your public statements, because you don't mention our need for quality.  You're actively hindering their introduction to SE by not setting expectations, either in new user onboarding, or public messaging.

Comment: @Servy: I read "**as** they try to learn programming" to mean "Stack Overflow is one thing we hope people will do when they are learning to program" not "Stack Overflow is how we hope people will learn programming". But in any case, it doesn't seem profitable to parse the outgoing CEO's comments too closely.

Comment: @fbueckert: One thing to remember about the blog is not many new users read it. Askers get many more hints on how to act from the Ask page and the first few comments they get then they ever will from a boring corporate blog post. New users don't (yet?) care about Stack Overflow. Helping them to care is in our (the community's and the company's) best interest.

Comment: @Makoto Your interpretation also wasn't spelled out. It's a fact that this site educates users, and no formal guidance has changed so far. We could discuss if and how we should cater to specific questions about learning, but we already have in the past. I tend to read vague statements as _nothing will change_ for now.

Comment: @ErikA:  I'm seeing the line **In many ways Stack Overflow’s specific rules for what is permitted and what is not are obstacles** as a signal of policy change.  You may see differently and I'd love to hear how.  Genuinely not interested in getting into a fight on this; looking for an objective answer.

Comment: @JonEricson The main justification for my interpretation is the whole referring to the site's quality standards as "obstacles to people asking questions" that they want to remove.  This is indicating they're not looking to try to encourage people to ask well researched, clear, details, specific questions (whether they're new to programming or not), as that's currently not an issue on the site (and so doesn't require any changes), but rather to encourage the asking of questions not currently considered acceptable.  We'll see if that interpretation pans out.

Comment: @Makoto: I think it's fair to say Joel would like to see Stack Overflow continue to serve the next generation of developers and the blog post reflects his thoughts on how that might happen. I'd say it's pretty much the opposite of an official change of direction since a new CEO will have some thoughts on that and ought to have some influence on the goals they will pursue for the company.

Comment: @JonEricson:  Serve **how**??  Are we going to be teaching them how to program or are we going to continue doing what we've always done (which then sired the Welcoming initiative)?  We can't keep doing this; we need to know *the* direction we're going or we're going to keep dancing around this problem.

Comment: @Servy: This might sound glib, but the quality standards have never produced quality content on the site. Only people can do that. The standards can help, but it's so frustrating to see good content downvoted simply because it doesn't have the trappings on quality. It should be possible for users to say they are still learning without being hassled about it. (But this is starting to look more like an answer than a comment.)

Comment: @Makoto That piece you're quoting is all from approximately a year ago, and in that piece it's more clear that Joel is talking about rules having an upside and a downside. I don't see a real indication of policy change, and you might think I got my head in the sand, but I think this is all mostly blah-blah. The only thing I've learned from that blog is that SO is looking for a new CEO, and it's surrounded by a bit of context about the actual issues it faces. Not a real indicator of policy change imo, but let's wait and see when that new CEO shows up.

Comment: @JonEricson What counts as, "trappings on quality"?  That seems like it needs clarification, because to me, good content is good content.  Learners can ask good questions, just as veterans can ask bad ones.

Comment: @ErikA:  It really does read to me like a wish-list for a candidate CEO, in some sense.  A CEO which is focused on making the site more diverse and welcoming does seem to be the overarching goal, but I wouldn't be surprised in the slightest if this included a CEO who had a focus on making the direction of the site one of teaching others.

Comment: It's quite easy to solve the problem and make everyone happy: let SO be the "halp me writ helo word" site, then start up a sister site for professional programmers. Let the sites share rep, mod privileges and meta. Those who want to be elementary school students/teachers can stay on SO and those who want to have professional programming Q&A can go to the sister site. Either SO starts such a site or some other company will. Just a matter of time. I personally don't care who owns it, I'll leave to that site the moment it opens up, never to look back.

Comment: such sites already exist, they're typically called "forums". there's a reason they never really grow to the size of SO

Comment: I'm not concerned about the "learn programming" part specifically, since programming is a life-long learning process, and this doesn't say that much about at which point we want them to come here. I am, however, quite concerned about the implication that our rules are big problems (due to the "even bigger problem" part). But the optimistic side of me thinks this was just phrased in a less than ideal way.

Comment: '*But the optimistic side of me thinks this was just phrased in a less than ideal way.*' - @Dukeling Seems like a lot of that has been happening recently. ~ *the pessimistic side*

Comment: @DavyM I was in the process of reading your answer. Sad to see you deleted it, presumably because of the downvotes? It's OK to post an answer here and get downvoted, because downvotes do not mean an answer is useless.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't see him saying that the rules are a big problem. The way I read that sentence is that snark, rudeness, and condescension are the big problem, not our rules. Though the rules can sometimes act as obstacles to new people learning programming (and I think we can all agree that they're not always perfect), I don't read it as Joel saying that they're the main problem here.

Comment: @Stijn I figured the downvotes were due to the fact that I was just making a conjecture about a potential reason, which isn't useful nor an answer to the question when I thought about it objectively. The downvotes didn't mean it was useless, but they led me to think about why my answer would actually be useful and I didn't come up with a reason why it was. But if you thought what you were reading was useful, then I can undelete it.

Comment: "The way I read that sentence is that snark, rudeness, and condescension are the big problem" - I really don't see such things on the C++ tag - the only one I watch. Are they _really_ common elsewhere, or are people using these terms when they mean "being downvoted and closed", which I _do_ see a lot of, and are quite correct in almost all cases.

Comment: @NeilButterworth:  It manifests in both ways.  You get people who decide to vocalize their objection to being downvoted/having their post closed, which is *routinely* met with snark, rudeness or condescension.  You also get people who commentate on posts *just* with snark (for instance, anything to do with code formatting or how it hurts someone else's eyes, etc).  That's been a problem since time immemorial, but the various initiatives to make the site more welcoming would only result in a more strict enforcing of the actual rules, which haven't *really* changed all that much.

Comment: @fbueckert: Your comment about wanting nothing more to do with SE could be read as either a simple mix-up between SE the network, SO the company and SO the site, or you apparently having so much of a personal stake in whatever the company does with SO, a site you barely participate on, that you're ready to throw the baby out with the bathwater, not content with simply ceasing participation on SO alone. Most high-profile SE users who hardly - or don't - participate on SO probably couldn't care less. What's it to you? (If you're worried that this'll extend to Arqade coddling n00bs... fair.)

Comment: @BoltClock It already does.  Arqade's been trending towards user focus for quite some time.  It's an argument I have on a rather regular basis in the Bridge.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Makoto's right but also a combination of certain tags, certain types of bad questions, and bad luck/time of day would result in a pile on in the comments of a brand new question back when I was still paying attention to the main page. I don't if that's changed recently but that used to be a thing.

Comment: @Makoto I really don't see either of those things with regularity enough to complain about. If it occurs, I think it must be different behaviours in different tag communities.

Comment: possibly related: [How to correct a CEO's misunderstanding of a project?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15436/168) TL;DR: Atwood has built a fairly robust system so that there is a chance that core users will be capable to handle even a mis-hired CEO, "You should not underestimate the role of _active_ individual contributors..."

Comment: @Lundin within the frame of your argument it's really unlikely for SE to want to split their userbase, as people come here because of the experts. If all of those experts leave, then this is basically w3schools with a quirky article system. Someone else might sometime, but i doubt that it'll ever be SE to do this. Also, with how progressive tech as a whole has gotten, I doubt any future site will fare better once people set their eyes on it as something they want to make theirs.

Comment: @Magisch The point is, the experts have already been leaving for several years and the quality of SO is dropping, so it will end up a trashy student site no matter. SE can chose to pick up what remains of the experts or it can let someone else have them -> the product -> the income.

Comment: Am I the only one who was deeply relieved by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325178/goodbye-and-thank-you-jaydles), thinking the PC circus was over - only to be flabbergasted by this new blog post once again?

Comment: @Magisch Based on my observations, there are more than enough experts who would actually *prefer* if we ease up on the rules a bit to make a split a viable idea. Although I very much empathise with your doubt that SE will ever do this, I also think a nontrivial bunch of users will disagree with such a decision so strongly that they just quit both sites, and the users who'd prefer less strict rules might just not care that much because we're not currently effective enough at enforcement to bother them (unlike on [workplace.se]...).

Comment: @mena: What makes you think Jaydles was responsible for all that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey maybe not *responsible*, but he did put his name on [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) blog post, which made ripples.

Answer (score 17):

The mission of Stack Overflow is to help coders help each other become better coders by sharing their knowledge with one another.

That means all people who write code:

- It means the programmers who are already here, who hang out here asking and answering questions and cleaning things up and keeping the place tidy and high-quality and generally shouldering the burden around here (and who are probably the ones reading this. Hi!).
- It also means programmers who don't do those things yet, and maybe programmers who won't ever do those things.
- And it means people who maybe just wrote their first line of code yesterday.

Stack Overflow is here to serve people who code and want to learn more about it, or help others learn more about it. That includes the "next generation of developers". It also includes the current "generation" of developers. And heck, it includes past generations of developers: all of our work here is built upon the shoulders of giants, from whom we continue to learn.

We haven't done a great job historically of serving the next generation of programmers. But learning to include those folks is not at odds with Stack Overflow's mission, which is **to help coders help each other become better coders**. It does all of us a disservice to think of that next generation as a "them" instead of as part of "us". There was a time in each of our lives when we'd never written a single line of code. But we each picked it up, somehow, and kept at it with the help of whatever resources were available to us. Books, maybe. User groups. A university department.

Eventually, Stack Overflow became a huge part of that resource landscape. It's what people turn to (or stumble upon) after they write their first script to automate some tedious part of their job and get hooked on that feeling you get when you first get a computer to *do something new* for you. (It's aliiiive!)

So, in short, no. Joel's not saying that the next phase of Stack Overflow's story is going to mean we require all our users to hold newbies' hands as they hunt and peck their way through their first function. He's saying that the next phase of Stack Overflow's story is going to involve us figuring out a way for that next generation, and any other coders who aren't served well by Stack Overflow today, to come join the community and find other coders to learn from and/or teach.

There's no "us vs. them" here. There's no "we'd rather help new users than require high quality content" dichotomy. No one wants to throw away everything we've built that works so well for so many people in order to serve some new audience. The goal is to help coders help each other, and that means different things to different coders.

That's a tall order and we'll need a big umbrella to fit it all in. But there's room for everyone under that umbrella--including room for the folks who are already served well by Stack Overflow today. There's no good to be found in pushing folks out from under that umbrella and into the rain. The only thing for it is to build a bigger umbrella.

Comment: "There's no good to be found in pushing folks out from under that umbrella and into the rain." ...Then why does it feel like that's exactly what SE is doing to us?  We get constant harping on how we're being mean to new users, that we're not supposed to downvote answers to bad questions, [or that we're completely wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/)?  SE has spent years ignoring it's established userbase, and suddenly it's implied we're the problem in the welcoming wagon?  How, exactly, is this *not* an, "us vs them" problem?

Comment: There's a lot to parse in here but honestly, [I think this is the fourth or fifth different mission](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that I've seen on the site.  This kind of gets to what I'm trying to bring to a head; if we have one mission, one clear and unambiguous directive, then how we get there becomes more of an implementation detail and produces less hand wringing.

Comment: These are both totally valid points, both of you. We have not done a good job over the last couple of years of actually communicating what's going on inside the company and how that translates to changes out here. It's getting better but it ain't good yet, and that leads to confusion and frustration for y'all. Making it clear what the one mission is everywhere we talk about it and clearing up those contradictions is key. So is making sure our current community feels valued and not villainized. We've been really bad at that lately. We want to make it better.

Comment: Admit it. For whatever reasons, established users and new users *absolutely* are at odds with each other. It is bad enough that I'm not sure it's feasible to reconcile. Whether they realize it or not, so far SE has chosen one side at the expense of the other. At the risk of invoking some long-standing taboo, there are other possibilities that don't hurt one side. For example, if two people absolutely do not get along with each other, one way is to separate them. Or at least stop forcibly putting them in the same room together.

Comment: Until things get clearer @hairboat, can we have a moratorium on announcements of *any* kind?  I really don't want there to be a disconnect between the stated expectations of the community and the stated expectations of the company which has been demonstrated to lead to lots of friction.  Lots of good efforts can die based on those disconnects.

Comment: A moratorium on announcements doesn’t mean decisions aren’t getting made, @Makoto. It just means the community is left completely in the dark. I’m not sure how that would be an improvement. Good will is in peril either way.

Comment: @Makoto I'd say let them keep talking. I prefer the transparency. If the message we take from this is that SE doesn't really know what the correct solution is, that's fine and totally understandable. They're trying to tackle some pretty hard problems here and I'm sure plenty of us are willing to provide input.

Comment: @CodyGray:  It basically forces a common language.  If an announcement should be made, then both parties should have the exact same working understanding of what the problem is that they're trying to solve and how it should be solved.  If we can't get *that*, then announcements are largely for show.

Comment: @Mysticial:  They're not being transparent, though.  [This is the *fastest* feature I've  seen get proposed, developed and released](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373160/1079354) ***ever*** to the Stack Exchange community, yet we're still stuck with broken search.  They're making a push towards *something*, but keeping mum on a lot of stuff we've been trying to engage them on for years - and in come cases, *decades*.  I don't doubt that they're tackling some hard problems.  What I doubt is what those problems really *are*, but they're in a different frame of mind than we are for it.

Comment: @Makoto Some transparency is better than none at all - even if the information they post seems out-of-place. I read official SE posts (or rather everything in general) not just to see what they say, but to gauge what's going on behind closed doors. Why are they saying this? Are they trying to hide something from us? Or perhaps they really don't know what they're doing and they need to say *something*. Are they trying to send a hidden message to some users, but not others?

Comment: To SE, it's very possible that us "established users" are very much like the "help vampires" on the main site constantly begging for information and harrassing the staff. And they need to say *something* to get us to shut up while they have their hands tied by something else.

Comment: @Mysticial:  I'd rather them admit that than kite us, honestly.  If we're being the problem, then we can actually *fix* that.  If they're not telling us we're the problem, then we're going to keep doing what we do.  I'm not a fan of hiding facts in plain view, frankly.

Comment: @Makoto Not to say this is the case, but just for the sake of conversation: Let's just say that SE has solidly chosen new users over the established ones and that they really don't care what happens to us now. IOW, we're worth nothing to them at this point since we don't answer Q's anymore and all we do is harass new users and complain on meta. They're not going to say that to us upfront. They will keep working towards that goal while providing just enough (mis)information to keep us from going up in arms. Then let the established users silently drop one-by-one.

Comment: @Makoto We've gotten some feedback along those lines on [M.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089), especially [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/316246#comment1030131_314348).  And, well, I think this is a product of their own actions, honestly.  SE has a communication problem.  We get lots of words about how they're working on it, complaints that we're too negative, and then...silence.  Until the next time we question SE's actions.  I'm getting a little cynical about this cycle.

Comment: @Makoto: So, um, I hope you recognize that adding the new user indicator was trivially easy and fixing search is, well, not. It's not as if that feature took away from anything else we were working on. Documentation is a much better example, I'd say.

Comment: @JonEricson:  I had [other thoughts on Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334291/1079354).  Had a few more on the Meta site that was stood up for a brief period of time for it, too but I can't find those anymore.  I respect that delivering that feature was easy and quick to do, but it doesn't really remove the taste in my mouth when we've been talking about search [for a *long* time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=improvements+to+search+is%3Aq).

Comment: Although I'll admit @JonEricson, I'm starting to get some of the same flashbacks when talking about or talking through some of the things I had seen with Documentation as I am talking about *this* now, so I think the best thing for me to do would be to retreat for a while...

Comment: @Makoto: Yeah. It's a _symbol_ of how you see our priorities. As far as it goes, it's even a useful symbol. But it's also incomprehensible to people who haven't bought into the narrative that we don't care about existing users. It also comes off as, I don't know, grouchy since the feature is so utterly inconsequential. You see it when you use the site and I imagine that bugs you. But it really doesn't _hurt_ the site in any way, does it? I'm just saying it's not a useful example for many employees to understand what you are experiencing.

Comment: That may be a prime disconnect @JonEricson:  I want to see changes which actively *help*.  A change like the Welcoming initiative may not have hurt, but I as a power user don't have the same philosophy into why it *helped*.  I don't want to clutter hairboat's inbox any further with this discussion, though; if you want to chat, we could take this to Chat later.  My position right now is that I'm quite mentally drained from this since I don't see a win for anyone right now.

Comment: I understand wanting to make people feel welcome. I haven't felt welcome on the site for a while, not by the community, but by the community team and mods from other sites. That doesn't seem to matter to the network. If I left tomorrow I suspect many people would be relieved. I wonder if other long term users feel this way. There's a lack of support for people who have put their neck on the line for the site for years. It's very saddening. I don't feel there's anyone I can turn to from your organisation for any type of support. But hey I'm from one of those minority groups we need to include.

Comment: @JonEricson If y'all were posting biweekly updates on what you're working on for search, what you've tried that didn't work, maybe even self-answered Q&A about problems you encountered and how you solved them, we could give you credit for that.  Probably a lot of credit!  But you don't, and so I can only assume that your management keeps saying "drop what you're doing and implement this welcoming feature", and so no actual search work is getting done.

Comment: @Yvette please don't leave :/. It's a shame that you feel this way, and I can only have flashbacks of Monica C.'s blog post here.....honestly 2018 wasn't a great year for SO.... And it's starting to feel like 2019 may end up being worse :/...

Comment: @Patrice ironically I feel support from our community of users, it's the 'employees of the network' that I feel incredibly alienated from. There's a lot that gone on behind the scenes. Some my fault, but not all my fault. I don't like the way things are handled and there's no one to turn to to say that. I feel users like me will be thrown under the bus as disposable and replaceable. Can you give me a link to Monica's blogpost?

Comment: @Yvette lemme try to see if I can find it :). I may ping you a bit later with it, I found it by happenstance.... But it kinda echoed what you said here. It started from a post whre someone complained about it on Twitter, and SO never did anything to backup the mods or anything: they just caved in in favor of the random Twitter user. I'll continue hunting it down and let you know once I find it

Comment: @Patrice Are you talking about this? https://medium.com/@cellio/dear-stack-overflow-we-need-to-talk-13bf3f90204f

Comment: @Yvette long bus transit today (lucky you: I am going to have a date with my daughter, so you wouldn't have had that update early without it :p).  https://medium.com/@cellio/dear-stack-overflow-we-need-to-talk-13bf3f90204f is the exact link I was looking for. Thx Rakete1111 :)!

Comment: @Yvette Colomb: Lucky you. I don't even feel support from the community (on this matter anyway - I know many of my meta answers get lots of support). Mostly because most of my views on this matter are at odds with the prevailing attitude. You might have noticed that I haven't bothered to weigh in on any of this, despite it being a topic that's close to me. I think you can guess why.

Comment: Whatever happened to us that we're now reading the end of the site as we know it into everything. I was just as hurt and negatively surprised by many of the changes in the last year, but we can't ever hope to have anything but an adversarial relationship with the company again if we take offense at every opportunity. I don't know, it's incredibly exhausting though.

Comment: @Magisch It really is exhausting.  The trust was broken with the welcome wagon, and that's led to this incredibly adversarial relationship.  I think a lot of it is that SE has taken that trust for granted, and wasn't expecting the backlash at all, so this last year's been misstep after misstep.  Some of it trying to repair that trust, and some of it just breaking it further.  Trust needs to be regained before that relationship can be repaired, and that's a very hard thing to do once it's been broken.

Comment: Are we going to be collectively holding the sword of damocles over their heads forever because of the welcome wagon, @fbueckert? Has anything actually materialized as a consequence that points to it actually being a breach of trust vs some mixed success communication?

Comment: @Magisch There's been plenty; new contributor icon implemented in record time.  HNQ questions being implemented as a result of someone on Twitter complaining, despite years of attempts at fixes on Meta.  SE staff implying repercussions in response to said Twitter spat.  And let's not forget yet another staff member telling us we've been completely wrong all these years.  There needs to be some middle ground for both sides, but that requires SE to rebuild the trust they have lost.  I wouldn't mind discussing this more in chat; don't need to clog up hairboat's inbox even more.

Comment: @fbueckert while i'm notably on the record of being upset about the HNQ incident (my top answer on all of meta is about that), I still regard the implemented changes as strictly positive on my end (giving more controls to sites and mods about what goes on there). I can take or leave the new contributor indicator, but so far I'm not seeing the strictly negative effects materializing.

Comment: Because!
When the sun shines, we shine together
Told you I'll be here forever
Said I'll always be your friend
Took an oath that I'm a stick it out 'til the end
Now that it's raining more than ever
Know that we still have each other
You can stand under my umbrella You can stand under my umbrella. Sorry <3

Comment: If anyone is interested, @Magisch and I discussed this a bit more [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1323/room-for-fbueckert-and-magisch).  I invite anyone who wants to read or weigh in to join.