# What's the precise and exact mission statement of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

As a follow-up to an earlier question of mine, [there was some ambiguity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381935/1079354) in reference to what the **actual** mission of Stack Overflow is.

I'm not looking to debate the matter nor am I looking to nitpick.  I just want a **clear and unambiguous** definition to what it *is*.

If we know and understand what it is, then we are better equipped as curators and [pseudo-]moderators to help with the site and to help achieve its ultimate goals.  Without it, we're stuck with going in an unclear and uncertain direction.

Comment: It seems quite clear to me: "**Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." Taken right from the [tour] page, also known as "about".

Comment: @CodyGray:  Yet there's enough ambiguity that an employee came out and said something *different*.  Instead of going through that song and dance again, let's just get this whole thing disambiguated once and for all.

Comment: They...didn't really. It's just a flourish of language, imprecisely using what appear to be synonyms in order to make nice prose for a blog. Don't read too much into it.

Comment: @CodyGray [Catija disagrees with that designation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381430/spurned-authors-deleting-their-questions-after-they-are-closed-as-duplicate#comment679268_381430).  That, along with other SE employees mentioning missions, is likely the impetus behind this question.

Comment: No disagreement there. Beginner questions have *always* been allowed on Stack Overflow, and that doesn't contradict with the statement I quoted. You can't "build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming" if you exclude beginner questions. Furthermore, since there's no brightline for what is "beginner" and what is "expert", it just leads to pointless arguments. That's not how we determine what is a good, on-topic question. We have a different set of standards, more focused on how the question is presented, which are much less ambiguous. @fbu

Comment: @CodyGray That said, attempts to pin down what, exactly, "everyone who codes" means, led to a sprawling conversation which showed just how different, "enthusiast and professional programmers" conflicts with, "everyone who codes".  Clearing up what, exactly, we're trying to do would be most useful to everybody.

Comment: So...the disagreement is whether we should cater to hobbyist programmers who aren’t very enthusiastic about it? I don’t know about you, but I think that’s extremely silly. Why does it matter? What does the enthusiasm level of a prospective asker about programming change about the way we run the site?

Comment: @CodyGray: Once we actually know what kind of mission they want for the site, *then* we can get into the weeds and nitpick.  Until then, anything like that is pretty premature.

Comment: I strongly feel that *we already know*. It has been made, and continues to be made, expressly clear all over the place, from the Tour to the Help Center to the UI. You’re just nitpicking over wording. Which, I agree can be quite fun. But avoid setting off the alarm bells.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I don't doubt I might be nitpicking, but if we're having decisions and features implemented or proposed based on a specific definition that the community isn't completely in the know about, then that only serves to fester *more* dissent and angst.  All I'm really trying to do is to put an end to any ambiguity.  Then, if there *is* a disconnect, both sides could at least work to resolve *that*.

Comment: ^ Abby's answer to that question of yours yesterday not only says what the mission of SO is but goes into quite some detail about it. This question doesn't seem to be substantively different in any way.

Comment: @TylerH:  This is a clean question to pose; instead of asking, "Oh, is this where we're headed now?", I'm asking, "Where are we headed?" Abby also did note that there was some ambiguity in the response she gave, so hopefully now this is an opportunity to clear up that ambiguity.

Comment: @TylerH:  Think of it like this; when I wrote *that* question, I thought I knew what the mission statement of the site was.  After receiving that answer, I realized that it was interpreted differently for employees and power-users.

Comment: Where in Abby’s answer do you see the conflict? I ask because I think you and I have the same understanding of the site’s mission, yet I didn’t find anything objectionable or contradictory in what Abby said. I mean, I’m a little concerned that building a bigger umbrella might mean more foolish ventures like Documentation or Stack Overflow TV that detract from Q&A. But certainly being a resource for *all* generations of programmers and prospective programmers is not in conflict with what you and I have been fighting for, and building, all these years.

Comment: The mission of the former executive management team was somewhat obvious.  They got a year from the investors to fix the SO problems but failed miserably.  So they were sent packing, what's next is anybody's guess.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I've got a few things to dash off to so I'll think on this a bit more thoroughly, but a hot-take would be **motivation**.  My motivation to continue curation on this site is directly tied to my desire to see this site be the best resource available for developers.  The motivation I see in Abby's post is more about coders helping coders and education, which is *incidental* and a direct side-effect, but not the focus.  If we're the best resource available for developers, education follows suit without question.  If we're focusing on helping developers, what will become of quality?

Comment: @CodyGray Re your first comment, sure, the tour says that, but the [About]() page says "Helping developers write the script of the future. 
Building communities where everyone who codes can learn and share their knowledge. 
Connecting developers with companies to help them find the right job, product, or service." That sounds a lot more like Hairboat's post, because both are focused on people. Your quote focuses on the library. It seems the site and company have different missions, missions that work well together (you can't have the library without the librarians), but still distinct.

Comment: Sorry that about link is supposed to go here: https://stackoverflow.com/company

Comment: @CodyGray:  "Coders helping coders" is too broad a phrase to use to define the situation with users asking us to help them with their debugging problem.  I know that this was **explicitly called out as something *not* desired**, but that only fuels the ambiguity.  Being clear about it makes things easier.  While the two interpretations I have aren't mutually exclusive, a slant can occur if we're more focused on helping developers and not really putting quality more at the forefront of our goals.

Comment: You already *know* the answer to this question. You also know that there's no way in heck that SO the company is *ever* going to come out and publicly admit it, because that would drive off the users who actually give a damn about this site - and who, coincidentally, are the only thing preventing it becoming yet another Experts Exchange. All we've ever got, and all we're ever *going* to get, are the same old half-truths and plausible denials that an abusive husband uses to keep his wife chained to him.

Comment: @IanKemp we are an inclusive group of people, as such, it would only be fair if we reverse the scenario too! '*All we've ever got, and all we're ever going to get, are the same old half-truths and plausible denials that an **abusive wife** uses to keep her **husband** chained to her.*' ~ (P.S. 'tis just a joke, put the pitchforks away!)

Comment: Clear and unambiguous: The mission of StackOverflow (Incorporated) is to maximize shareholder investment. Period. The mission of StackOverflow(.com) is to "... to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." To the extent that there is tension between those 2 missions, I'll give you 3 guesses to figure out which way that tension is going to resolve.

Comment: One might as well bring this up: [this answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/1233251) has only stirred the pot, and we're still feeling chewed up on the subject because of it. If an SO employee shows up with such a controversial statement, it's fairly easy to question the side the company's on.

Comment: @Hans Passant: *[Management Team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management)* lists, not including members of the board of directors, 11: Joel Spolsky, David Fullerton, Cassie Montrose, Alex Miller, Guy Zerega, Jerry Raphael, Khalid El Khatib, Mary Ferguson, Mihir Pathak, Sean Bave, and Will Cole. Have they all been canned?

Comment: The company has ~300 employees, only a small number of them are involved with Q+A.  I only know of Spolsky and Hanlon, the latter left about 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 11):

The mission is right there in [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming

Or, to use Abby's particular wording, which as far as I can see is meant to express the same thing:

> The mission of Stack Overflow is to help coders help each other become better coders by sharing their knowledge with one another.

That hasn't changed, and to such extent as anyone tries to change it, we - the established community who care about this mission - should resist. Ultimately, the site cannot thrive without us and we can defy any attempt from above to change the site's direction in a way that is incompatible with the mission as we see it.

But I think you're tilting at windmills if you perceive [hairboat's answer to you two days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381935/1709587) as such an attempt. Nothing in it is incompatible with the established mission written in the help center. It is perfectly coherent to simultaneously think all three of the following things:

1. Our fundamental mission is to create and maintain a library of knowledge
2. Programmers of any level of experience and commitment to the craft are welcome to contribute to that mission, so long as their contributions are good
3. Our current culture is scaring off the next generation of coders who would otherwise become valuable contributors, as well as some undefined set of "other coders who aren't served well by Stack Overflow today" (presumably the women and ethnic minorities we've previously been told we alienate), and that's a big problem that we need to solve

Unlike Abby, I don't agree with point 3. But her belief in it does not mean she views the site's mission differently from the rest of us. Thinking we should be nicer to newbies is not *inherently* at odds with our core mission, as Abby makes sure to state herself, explicitly, in the penultimate paragraph her answer. Lord knows I am no supporter of the Welcome Wagon, but not every single expression of the belief that we should be more inclusive automatically represents a betrayal of the site's core mission, and we shouldn't be acting like it does.

Comment: '*but not every single expression of the belief that we should be more inclusive automatically represents a betrayal of the site's core mission, and we shouldn't be acting like it does.*' - Absolutely, however, it does seem that any of the outwards correspondence that SO has to the public (the blog or Twitter) seems to involve berating / talking down on the current state of the site or its contributors, yet, on the meta answers that we get, the tune changes significantly and we get the age old song and dance '*We know we've been bad at communicating and we're working on that...*'.

Comment: I don't think these two definitions express the same thing. The first one strongly reflects how I see stackoverflow.com, while the second one seems to describe sites like [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/), [r/learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming) etc.

Comment: I don't think these two definitions express the same thing. The SECOND one strongly reflects how I see statckoverflow.com, while the first point seems to preach that question-and-answer structures are the best or only way to educate or build a knowledge base. At times I have discovered bugs in libraries that I just wanted to share on stackoverflow but know that it would have been marked as a non-question and therefore implied on this site as not valuable knowledge to help programmers.

Answer (score 2):

We are here to build content that will stand the test of time.

Stack Overflow was built to facilitate that endeavor. Management is in place to keep it online. That is the way the world works.

I know you aren't interested in debating what the mission statement is, but the interpretation of how to accomplish the goal seems to be the crux of the issue here; which is to say, the mission statement is clear, the degree to which each distinct action we as a community take contributes is not.

The how of building this "repository of knowledge" is where we seem to get confused sometimes.

Part of creating content that stands the test of time is ensuring that the knowledge being shared is of value to future visitors, and an aspect of that often overlooked by people not familiar with the goals here is that not every question should be answered.

> The goal of Stack Overflow is not "answer my question" but "let's collaboratively build an artifact that will benefit future coders". -Atwood

Curating the questions which are not helping build the library and are not helping future visitors is an important distinction which is implied but not often covered explicitly in the mission statement or in related content put out by official sources.

Content curation is very important. It ensures that the material a future visitor sees is high quality. Creation and curation go hand in hand. However, there is an important distinction: curating can never create. At the point where we are removing more quality content in the name of curation than we are creating quality content then we have failed.

> [Stack Overflow] is a place where a busy programmer can invest a few minutes with as little friction as possible, and get something tangible from the community in return. -Atwood

The balance between creating content and curating it is a delicate balance. While there does need to be barriers in place to protect the site from being overrun by low quality, there also needs to be a way for high quality to be encouraged.

That there is an overlap here in both directions -- in that sometimes low quality is accidentally encouraged, and that sometimes high quality content is removed -- is only natural. So long as we stay range bound to a balance we will continue to abide by the mission statement of Stack Overflow.