# We’re bringing advertisements for technology courses to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, design, advertising

**UPDATE:** We have concluded this pilot study, and will discontinue serving advertisements for technology courses on Stack Overflow starting May 31st, 2023. With your feedback on this post and the ads' performance metrics, we have gathered sufficient information that will guide us to develop new products you hopefully will find helpful. Thank you all for the time, patience, and feedback offered.

---

Beginning in late January, we’re partnering with two online course providers to present sponsored technology course recommendation advertisements on Stack Overflow. This is a pilot study for this type of ad, and we’ll be running tests over the course of a few months to develop an understanding of the value that course recommendations add to the platform.

On the day we launch, you will begin to see course recommendations from our first two partners - Pluralsight and Udemy. These recommendations will initially appear only for a subset of site traffic. Here’s what it will look like:

[image: Four example course recommendation ads, each of which contains four courses. The ads also contain a header and a subtitle, which vary slightly.]

When we show you these ads, we will display them in the existing sidebar ad slot, rather than create an additional ad slot dedicated to course recommendations. Our primary aim is to improve the usefulness and relevance of our ad slots to users. If you would like to see how this ad slot fits into the overall layout, please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3vk3.jpg).

The pilot will last approximately four months, and we'll be running experiments (e.g. altering the layout or design of the ad) during this time. We plan to partner only with Pluralsight and Udemy for the duration of the pilot study. Based on the results of the pilot study and your feedback, we'll decide on next steps. That includes a determination as to when we will open this ad slot up to additional partners that create technology courses relevant to Stack Overflow (provided they meet our advertiser guidelines).

#### Will these ads be targeted based on my browsing history?

We will base the ads on your *Stack Overflow* browsing history, **only if** you have opted in to tracking. Here are the ways you may have already opted in:

- You **opted in** to “targeting cookies” in our cookie management dialog box.
- You **opted in** for ad personalization via [the “Activity data” section of your account settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) (note that this setting is ‘opt-in’ by default, but only controls your privacy settings if you’ve already opted in to targeting cookies):

  [image: An image of section titled "activity data" on the Account Settings page]

**If you would like to opt out,** you have two options:

- You can opt out at any time by opening “Cookie Settings” in the footer of the page, and disabling “targeting cookies.”
- You can also opt in or out at any time by flipping the toggle circled above on [your account settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current).

Opting out *either* on your account settings page *or* in the cookie management dialog box will cause Stack Overflow to stop serving personalized recommendations (but will not stop recommendations from showing up entirely). If you are not logged in, then we will only use your cookie management settings.

And, as always, [we do not and will not sell your personal information to 3rd parties](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy).

#### What course recommendations will I see if I opt out of targeting?

If you opted out of personalized recommendations, we will still recommend courses to you - however, the courses will be based upon other non-personal data, such as the popularity of the course, or the question you’re currently looking at.

#### Where can I see what data Stack Exchange has about my account?

Stack Exchange offers our GDPR-compliant [privacy and data management options](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr) to all users worldwide. If you would like to submit a request to export your data from Stack Exchange, you may do so using the [GDPR request form](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request).

---

If you have questions or feedback about the design we’ve selected, please feel free to provide that feedback here.

*(Please note that the current iteration of this project is already built as of this announcement. Any feedback provided now will be weighed in future revisions of the course recommendations system, but please do not expect feedback to be incorporated before the initial release.)*

Comment: Why would we actively pursue leading users away from the platform?

Comment: Well, when you partner with those sites, then could they offer a short course on how to effectively use Stack Overflow? How to ask, how to answer, how to do reviews etc. Might be more accessible than having a lot of help pages to read through. You then could also suggest those course when one is question banned for example.

Comment: @Tom But that would require the intent of educating users constructively to contribute to knowledge rather than cash flow, and not just mindlessly shipping them off to more for-profit companies. Can't have that now, can we?

Comment: @KevinB (Very) broadly speaking, courses perform a different function than Stack Overflow does. They provide comprehensive introductions to domain-specific topics, rather than providing answers to users' specific questions. We see them as complementary services.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Well, I would say that the company tries to educate people in some ways. They improved the "question closed" banner, updated the corresponding help pages a bit, added a wizard, are on their way to add a staging ground. So I guess the issue isn't that they don't want to, but they don't seem to be as successful with that as we hope they were.

Comment: Are those courses helping build our community? would users using them be pushed toward SO to answer any lingering questions they have from the courses?

Comment: Who is quality assuring recommendations? The few Udemy courses I have done in my specialist areas were terrible but "recommended". Now SO will be ranted about for bad course recommendations and bad manners.

Comment: @Tom: It already exists (though it could be out of date). Our very own [Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186035/policy-and-rationale-for-making-close-votes-invisible-to-most-users/186047#186047) has  [a Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange course on Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites) (about 25 lessons, about 5 minutes each). It was once [up on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oie8D4vCbAE) (but it was removed; the whole YouTube channel was deleted). This would be a good time to make it available for free.

Comment: Just curious... but what type of community discussion is this question seeking? Is this asking about the visual design of the ad, and that's it; accompanied by a blog post? Are we supposed to comment on the "course recommendations system"? Perhaps some insights into how we as users are targeted would be useful.

Comment: Where can we see the pool of offered courses?

Comment: Should I read "Use my on-site activity to show more relevant content (recommended)" as, "Sell my personal data to a third party"? I think my browsing history is personal. As ever, if its free, you are the product.

Comment: I think the algorithms wouldn't understand that I'm not interested in courses of the questions I'm browsing through and neither am I interested in courses outside my scope.

Comment: @user10186832 - probably worth noting that Slate is a long time contributor to the network.  New username for staff work.  So I'm sure they appreciate the welcome, but they're not new. :-)

Comment: So the tl;dr is "we are placing other types of ads in the existing ad slot using the tracking information you are already sharing with us". Was it even required to make a post about that change?

Comment: Ad-blocker ready and working.

Comment: What a coincidence that those other companies selling courses appear to be owned by Prosus as well. https://www.prosus.com/companies

Comment: I still think the job offerings were better but I guess the revenue would be bigger from those type of ads instead.

Comment: I really enjoy these posts of SE announcing a new kind of ad because of the freak-outs of people who, for some reason, in 2023, after we've been bombarded with in-page web ads for >20 years, have yet to have trained their minds to just ignore them.  SE gets some revenue and continues to exist. Your brain adapts if you give it a chance.  Do so, then find something _real_ to worry about.  Like high-rep rep-farmers answering stupid (and duplicate) homework questions showing no research whatsoever.

Comment: @davidbak I don't worry about that. There is no stopping it, so why worry about it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to partner with Udemy, which is well-known for (allowing) large-scale plagiary on their platform?

Comment: StackOverflow does need to make money. It's a shame that the courses that are advertised will probably not be very helpful.

Comment: @KevinB There's not really competition between Stack Overflow and pluralsight/udemy/edX etc. We actively close questions asking for such tutorials here. "Sending users away from the site" is a stretch. Technically any link to another website that is posted on SO is doing the same thing, but we don't disallow those.

Comment: @TravisJ A top-level tag is required even for staff when posting on Meta, and they have always used [meta-tag:discussion] for announcements, often without any call for a response of a particular kind.

Comment: Tough crowd. They're just ads, for goodness sake. At least they're making an effort to give us ads that are vaguely appropriate. We've had some very inappropriate ads on the network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inappropriate-advertisements?tab=Votes

Comment: The real question is, how long will we be able to opt-out? I just noticed on instagram you can no longer disable/opt-out of 'suggested posts'. How long until those making decisions find ways to justify giving even more UI space for paid advertisement? Shame to see the stack go this route..

Comment: @KevinB Actually, this wouldn’t be such a bad idea. The Stack Overflow format is pretty terrible for thorough, systematic learning that requires the learner to internalise a number of concepts and techniques at once, which is where courses and tutoring shine.

Comment: @PM2Ring "Tough crowd" As opposed to what crowd...? Is there actually anyone anywhere who _likes_ being the focus of advertising?

Comment: @Lundin Sure: people who are actually in the market for that product / service. But the point of my previous comment is that since *some* advertising is inevitable on the site we should be happy that SE is making the ads (relatively) on-topic. We don't have to *like* the ads, but hopefully we can at least tolerate them.

Comment: Can you open a patreon instead? I'd pay you not to sell me stuff... I don't want extra permissions, favoritism, or even a badge in return. PLEASE let me pay you so you don't show ads to me or others.

Answer (score 72):

Four months...that's a long time.

I just triple checked my settings to see if I'd ever see them, and it *looks* like I wouldn't, but there's still some feedback that needs to be provided about this...if you'll receive it, I suppose.

1. **People don't come to Stack Overflow for this.**  A lot of the feedback and user engagement about how they want to use Stack Overflow as a place to learn isn't to be conflated with taking an online class to learn.  They want *us* to teach them and/or be accessible to help them learn.  I personally don't think that either goal is tenable, in any short or long term, but I also especially don't think that someone asking a question about their Java application suddenly needs a course about Docker.
2. **This muddies the actual purpose of the site.**  What is Stack Overflow to upper management, anymore?  [We haven't received anything clear.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381992/1079354)  So, it feels like this is just something being thrown against the wall with the hope that it'll stick.  For some people, they probably won't care; this is out of sight, out of mind, so it's no biggie.  For the ***vast majority of people I know that use Stack Overflow***, they do so unauthenticated, so they're unshielded from this advertisement.  That'll take their attention away from why they're here in the first place, and I have a slight (and trust me it is very slight) concern that this'll drive them off.
3. **Seriously, what is it that you want to accomplish?**  Why are we doing this?  Do we *really* want to use Stack Overflow as a platform where people can learn how to code?  Or, and perhaps simpler, do these partner companies just want a bigger loudspeaker to amplify their offerings?

I'm already [at a point where I don't believe that Stack Overflow is acting with a lot of the interest in the community or mission](https://scribe.rip/the-trust-thermocline-explains-how-companies-suddenly-lose-customers-and-employees-2657c9535e6a), so this will be what it is.  The only thing that I'm just suggesting is that y'all have to figure out what your identity is, and *quick*.  This isn't the type of ad [that I'd care about or find relevant](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/), so your marketing it to me is an abrupt turn away from this.

Comment: Ah, yes.   The [Trust Thermocline](https://twitter.com/garius/status/1588115310124539904).  One of the most profound and satisfying things I've ever read on Twitter. (granted, that's a low bar.)

Comment: At this point... the tour probably needs an update: *Ask questions, get answers, **no distractions***

Comment: This project is the conclusion of a fair amount of user research, so I'd caution against saying that the desire/utility aren't there. We've done our research in part because this is a revenue-generating feature, and we hope it will become an important one. But, we will take the time needed to fully evaluate both the efficacy of the ads themselves, and whether they're having any kind of undesirable effects on the community. Any significant negative impact to the community would prompt us to re-evaluate our strategy for this feature, just as we would with any feature.

Comment: I've never met someone who wanted to see more advertisements... rather, i've only seen people who wanted the advertisements they were required to see to be more relevant. I think it's fair to assume the latter was the target of the research?

Comment: @Slate:  In my experience on the site, user research has always yielded dubious results at best with some strongly held conventions about where the site has gone when it comes to Meta.  But I'd rather acquiesce than beat that horse again; your numbers have more concreteness than my instincts, after all.

Comment: Why are you complaining? This is a way to generate revenue that is needed to keep this site running. If this is not the kind of ad you wish others to see, what would you recommend? At least it's related to the topic of Stack Overflow: programming courses. It's not like SO is changing direction. It's just an ad.

Comment: @Dharman:  I'm giving my feedback.  While I could see why one would want to interpret it as a "complaint"...which honestly just makes me want to give feedback even *less* ...it's really not *intended* to be a complaint.   For a period of time, ads that were run were super relevant to programming - things like IDEs or profiling tools or other things related directly to the industry were selected as ads.   It's how I found IntelliJ and YourKit, after all.  With this, I'm of the impression that the site wants to cater to the audience that comes here, looking for educators and leaves frustrated.

Comment: @Dharman:  So while yes, I could see someone say that a programming course is related to programming...I would respectfully disagree.  We've always been a Q&A site.  We've only orthogonally been related to education.  This muddies those waters, and this is the feedback I wanted to provide.

Comment: @Dharman:  If you think I'm complaining, then there's really not much I can do about that.  I don't feel the need to soften the blow or try to alter my language about this.  My perspective is only one perspective, and I'm far from the loudest or most influential voice in the room, so I'm just speaking my mind on it.  It'd be better to know and understand what direction the company thinks these ads will move the site in besides the one that I'm *concerned* about, which is...a place to get tutorials and learning on the cheap.

Comment: @Dharman:  If my concern is overblown I'd be happy to be proven wrong.  I just need someone to take into account my distrust about all of this, and "oh this is just an ad" hits.  The.  *Wrong.* Note.

Comment: Re *"Do we really want to use Stack Overflow as a platform where people can learn how to code?"*: I think ["we" do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwpFzAR4FX4&list=PLX8jr8KmM50aaaHp7mP-iWaz7UZC8pbRK&t=24m24s). - *"We want our users to not think of themselves ... as consumers, but to think of themselves as learners. ... New types of content: Articles,* ***courses***, *blogs, and challenges"*. Though I expected something more ambitious than ads for external entities.

Comment: @PeterMortensen:  Learning how to program from Q&A has the same texture as learning how to land a plane in an emergency from YouTube videos.  Sure, there's a lot of learning you can accomplish in both situations and given the circumstance you may have *slightly* more of a clue than none, but there's a whole lot of trust and expectation that we kinda gloss over there...

Comment: Hmm. I learned how to program from Q&A on Stack Overflow. You've now encouraged me to go learn how to land a plane. Unfortunately, I don't learn very well from YouTube videos and mostly hate watching videos altogether. Do you have any other suggestions for where I can learn to land a plane in an emergency?

Comment: It kinda depends on how you use SO to learn, I primarily answered questions here rather than using it for a tool to find answers. the simple act of solving lots of real-world problems from developers around the world was a great source for expanding my problem solving abilities. Asking questions on the other hand... doesn't seem like it'd be a great way to learn a whole lot, as ideally you'd quickly get to the point where you can solve them yourself and have little reason to ask. I'm not so sure there's such a wealth of great questions to answer these days.

Comment: The flaw of these arguments is that the purpose of this might not necessarily be something that benefits SO at all. You are reasoning as if every change to SO must logically be a benefit for SO. But Prosus could deliberately try to generate business for Udemy and SO be damned - whatever gives most profits.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I would have suggested _Flight Simulator_, and some universities do have full-blown simulators, but sometimes I feel like that's like watching a movie with extra steps.   But more seriously, yes, I won't deny that one can learn from Q&A.  Asking questions is how people learn things (a-la the famous "[redacted] around and find out").  However, the goal of Q&A isn't to _explicitly_ teach someone an entire career or an entire profession.  That's where the YouTube analogy comes in.

Comment: @Lundin:  On its face, your perspective is...how to put it nicely...a bit silly?  Leaving the acquisition to the side for now, if Stack Overflow doesn't make changes that are towards its own benefit - however "benefit" is measured - then these changes are very explicitly burning money.  Burning money is *not* ideal when you have to manage and administer *really* expensive infrastructure to have the service at all.

Comment: Sure but I'm just saying that if something, whatever it might be, is of great benefit to another company owned by Prosus and not to SO as such, they will pick that route. Therefore all decisions affecting SO are not necessarily made for the benefit of SO.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of this argument. People come to Stack Overflow because they don't know something about programming and they want to. Sometimes they come just to learn, and sometimes they come to solve a specific problem. More and more often, the people joining or visiting are less and less knowledgeable about programming. Showing them links to tutorials gives them a pathway to increase their knowledge, which is a net good thing on its own, but has a secondary benefit of, if the user returns to SO, they are now more knowledgeable, and more likely to provide useful content.

Comment: This isn't as silly as you think Lundin's suggestion is; it's the same logic behind why citizens have to pay taxes for schools in their areas, regardless of whether they have kids themselves. You benefit from living in an educated society. This is a furtherance toward that goal, so is good enough for that reason. That it also puts money in SO's coffers is two birds w/ one stone. That's... basic business.

Comment: @TylerH I don't disagree that there's value in learning opportunites existing on SO. ***I don't see any value in this one.*** It's nothing more than a cheap partnership between SO and an aggressively marketed paid tutorial site.

Comment: "I'm already at a point where I don't believe that Stack Overflow is acting with a lot of the interest in the community or mission."  Yeah, that much has fairly clear for a good long while now, and blatantly obvious since 2019.

Comment: @TylerH:  I think you missed my point.  I didn't say that people don't come to Stack Overflow to learn *at all*, I said they come *expecting to be taught by us*.  There is a key, subtle difference there that we can't really ignore.  Beyond that, I believe that you're overflowing with optimism about the value opportunities beyond one's intrinsic goal of learning how to do X.  What's the chance of them giving it back to the community, *and* the chance of that being well-received?  I'd want to do some analysis but I don't imagine the chances are particularly *high*.

Comment: "Muddies the purpose of the site". As a for-profit company, isn't the purpose of the site to make money? They do this as accommodatingly as they can to increase traffic but just b/c we come for coding answers, does not mean that is the only purpose of the site.

Comment: I'm kinda lost on this feedback tbh? How is an ad for a course on docker/AWS/ML/etc less of a good fit for SO than one for an IDE or a profiling tool, that you slot into the "acceptable/decent ads" category? If anything, i'm *not* coming to SO to get told what IDE to use, but if I'm looking at "how to do <basic task> in docker", it seems like I'm the exact target audience for a "doing things in docker" course?

Comment: @mbrig:  You'd know if you've taken a course or two online...  The problem here is that the tool is a *suggestion* and it's not something you'd *need*, so your expectations are a lot lower.  If you're looking at how to do something in Docker, then you have an explicit *want* for that course to be of-quality and your expectations are a lot higher.  The most satisfaction you get from buying something is if you're pleasantly surprised, not if you're just OK with the results.

Comment: @Makoto - If someone has an "explicit want" for a quality course, where would you send them? Is there someone offering higher-quality courses, that would make for a better partnership? Or, is the idea that courses are a waste of time, and no one should bother with them, as there's superior ways to learn X topic?

Comment: @ScottyJamison: That's hard to say.  Courses are often hit or miss for people, and teaching styles vary wildly between teachers, domains and expertise levels.  Not everyone finds or derives value out of the courses that are taught, nor are they all readily applicable to what they need to do to solve their problem.  I feel like, honestly, if someone were asking me for recommendations for a course to begin with, I'd want to presume that they have a few years of experience doing something with programming; otherwise, they're going to be *super* confused.

Comment: @ScottyJamison:  That is to say, just marketing it to someone - anyone - who just wants to write some code without a lot of basic understanding of it is dangerous and a bit misleading.  You won't be a programmer overnight just by taking a course, y'know.

Comment: and yet... "Learn python in days!" ads from these companies are all over the place. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @KevinB:  Yep.  Not much you can do about that in general but I would hope that *this* site still has some integrity left to say no to that kind of advertisement.

Comment: So, perhaps a "Courses for intermediate-level programmers" header above the ad would help with your concerns? Or something to that effect - something that tries to show that these courses aren't great for absolute beginners. (Not that I'm recommending this or not, just wondering)

Comment: @ScottyJamison:  Don't think so.  Education is a double-edged sword in that you have to market pretty broadly in order to attract a clientele.  Self-evaluation of your programming skills is always a dicey proposition since you could have 10-15 years of experience in the software development industry but all you ever did was low-level assembly testing.  There's a niche and a sweet-spot that courses can hit, but I don't think there's a lot of benefit in pairing that with the Stack Overflow experience since people will just assume that we're here to teach them.

Comment: From the perspective of the companies providing these courses, what would be an ethical way for them to market their material then? What websites (who actually care about the advertisements they host) should host advertisements related to these courses? Or, should they only advertise on platforms willing to advertise anything without a second thought? Or, perhaps it's just unethical for online courses to try and advertise, and they should get their content out through other means, like word of mouth? In other words, what would be a proper way for them to reach their intended audience?

Comment: I ask, because yes, advertising to the stackOverflow userbase means you'll be reaching lots of people who don't need your content (as is the case with any advertisement). From what I understand, you don't like this, because it means, unlike with IDEs, they'll be putting trust into a product that might let them down (and I'll add, it would be a wasted time commitment). But, is that an inevitable reality of how online courses work, or is there a way to reach the audience that actually needs their content while avoiding the people who don't.

Comment: @ScottyJamison:  I don't think the course providers are exactly at fault here since there is *some* value in the courses they offer but there's not a lot of time between asking a question on Stack Overflow and seeing the ad to consider *what* that value intrinsically is.  I remain firm in that this muddies the intention of a Q&A site in which people also just so happen to use it to be taught something.

Answer (score 43):

Suggestion: include a button / link to display the explanation about how the course offering was curated and why it's being shown.

Comment: Hey - I actually think something like this is a really good idea, and I'm going to make sure the team has seen it. Can't guarantee it'll get prioritized (or how much info it can reasonably contain), but I circulated it a bit and folks do think it has utility :)

Answer (score 28):

Did the previous partnering, or collaborating, with Pluralsight (from Story Assessments) contribute any lessons to be learned here? It seemed kind of like a dead end.

A lot of experts in their field are here on Stack Overflow, and even more visit without necessarily participating in posting. The developer population in general uses Stack Overflow at a much higher rate than other sites, and quite a lot of them could teach the courses linked here. Most of them took courses with much more rigor than simple online tutorials dressed up as learning experiences.

I understand the desire to monetize something out of this space, but this doesn't seem like a very efficient way to do it.

The power that Stack Overflow has is its access to some of the world’s most prolific tech content producers. If anything, that should be taken advantage of by giving that group more access to areas where content can actually be created. While systems like [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) fell on their faces, it was not for a lack of content creation; it was a lack of integration that failed.

If Stack Overflow truly pairs well with basic online tutorials, we should just create a space that users can create themselves. A separate space from Stack Overflow, just as Udemy and Pluralsight are.

> "The Documentation system, as introduced in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1), is a way for Stack Overflow users to leverage the community to create documentation assets, such as tutorials and example code for general use cases of a specific language, technology, tool, or framework in situations where no official first-party documentation exists." -[Docs tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/documentation/info)

This was really not a bad idea; it was just not given enough of its own space. Docs needed its own exchange, its own reputation sandbox, and the ability for the community to moderate content more strictly. It should at least be part of the conversation if more work is to be done on recommender systems or learning integration at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Docs had more problems besides separate rep and moderation - the wiki-style concept of docs doesn't mesh well with the SE model, leading to various issues with reputation and ownership. Longer, broader content such as tutorials is also inherently harder to validate and has more problems with plagiarism. Then there's "Docs light" aka "Collectives Articles", which has its own set of issues. So simply creating a docs.SE would not solve anything - we would need to have many long and hard conversations before even thinking of reviving Docs if we don't want to start the next dumpster fire.

Comment: I am glad you agree that the integration of Docs was problematic, especially in that it needed its own space, reputation, and community moderation. Creating Docs.SE would address all of those issues, but certainly there were other aspects that need work. We would need the people actually creating content to be part of the conversation of how to move forward with rounding out the balance of turning a feature of that nature into something that fit in the learning space.

Comment: I'd rather that StackOverflow didn't try to go into docs. That seems like an entirely different product. Lets just have StackOverflow focus on doing what it does best, being a Q&A site. Nothing stopping some other company from coming up with a collaborative docs site. I mean, yes, the concept sounds really nice, I'd just be worried about having SO split their attention between two very different products.

Comment: @ScottyJamison - I definitely agree, and I think that overall the community didn't necessarily blend well with the idea of providing "documentation" in place per se. That said, there is clearly a place and desire for something for free form. To some degree each of these newer features touch on that idea, but it is always a glancing blow. Specifically, we lack a place for users to create "code for general use cases". In some aspects that is done with dupe targets or canonicals, so to speak, but it does seem that there is a place for that somewhere here, if something were to be attempted.. imo

Answer (score 20):

We're programmers. Those who don't want to see the courses will probably implement a Tampermonkey script to make the suggestions go away.

So, who will see the ads?

- people who don't know how to Tampermonkey
- people who don't want to Tampermonkey

You could make this easier for everyone by providing a switch to "See online courses" or not.

Comment: Related: [stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/)

Comment: Also people who _can't_ Tampermonkey due to browser extensions being blocked in the office :)

Comment: @Leponzo If you're speaking from experience, hang in there. Life gets better. Hugs.

Answer (score 16):

Let's say, theoretically, I have built a Udemy course. Is there a way that I can get my course recommended as part of this pilot? Or is this out of the control of a course content creator?

This type of thing is important and will impact the [revenue share](https://support.udemy.com/hc/en-us/articles/229605008-Instructor-Revenue-Share) that Udemy has with its instructor community. Based on that linked page, I assume that this falls under "Udemy Advertisement" and the smaller share split.

Comment: Udemy provides us with a catalogue of courses related to technology. If you've created a course that is relevant to Stack Overflow, it may appear in the catalogue that is sent to Stack Overflow, and therefore, may appear in an ad here. For your second question, we'd strongly recommend connecting with Udemy to understand what your revenue share would be for courses you created for Udemy, to the extent they are part of this promotion on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14):

> [image]
> You can also opt in or out at any time by flipping the toggle circled above on your account settings page.

Doesn't that setting affect non-ad-related parts of the UI as well as ads?

If so, are you saying that if I don't want targeted ads, I have to live with a degraded experience in the non-ad parts of the site?

---

*(I don't see ads anyway because of my rep level, but I'm viewing this from the perspective of a user who hasn't got enough rep to disable ads.)*

Comment: My understanding is, that checkbox is what enables the "Interesting" tab's magic, aka the home page while logged in. and if i'm understanding correctly, your rep level wouldn't disable these ads, it just disables the ads that show up between the question and answers and possibly another slot on the right column.

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks. The "home page" as in https://stackoverflow.com? I don't see any ads on that page. But again, whether **I** do is largely irrelevant to my question above, which is about the average user experience, not my user experience. :-)

Comment: Yea, there should be one within js-sidebar-zone... but it's not showing for me either at the moment with the blockers down, i just get a blank space with a #hireme div. Maybe whatever ad they're trying to show there is broken :shrug:

Comment: But, yes, the home page as in https://stackoverflow.com. my point was the reduced ads privilege/option is just reduced, not remove, so it *should* still be showing us ads, and i do still routinely see ads when viewing logged in with incognito, which is where these specific ad blocks would be displayed. The ads that get removed are primarily banner ads rather than blocks

Comment: Apologies for the delay. We've been looking into this, and don't quite have a final answer yet. However, so far as we can tell, the "use my on-site activity" toggle hasn't controlled any on-site features since Jobs was decommissioned. That includes the "interesting" tab (cc @KevinB). As things stand right now (before release), you can flip this toggle on or off and should see no impacts to the UI on-site. (1/2)

Comment: After release, this option will provide an _additional_ method to restrict the ways we target you for advertisements. However, if you don't want to see any targeted ads on the site and/or do not want us to store targeting cookies for your data, revoking your consent to targeting cookies is the canonical way to effect that change - not this toggle. (2/2)

Answer (score 12):

The servers don't pay for themselves. So if it brings in more revenue without getting in the way of content then you have my blessing.

Answer (score 12):

This is more of a question for the community, but, why all the hate? For me, these ads seem just as relevant and useful as all of the other random programming-related ads I see on Stack Overflow (meaning, they're really not all that interesting—I don't care about 99.9999% of ads I see, as I'm sure is the case with most people). I appreciate that they're (somewhat) clearly marked as ads, they're at least related to a topic I care about, and they aren't distracting. And, if this trial-run works, it means that a good portion of the community found these ads to be interesting, which would be another plus.

Perhaps, people have had really bad experiences with these courses? And feel that promoting them in any way degrades the value of Stack Overflow? I've never taken one, so I don't know what they're like, but I sort-of doubt their quality could be that bad (at least, it can't be worse than any of the other stuff currently being advertised).

So, I guess I'm just wondering if there's some sort of negative vibe associated with these classes, that I'm entirely unaware of, such that advertising these courses is much worse than advertising all of the other random programming junk that gets advertised.

Comment: Relatedly, advertising programming courses (assuming, of course, that they're good) seems to be a good way to provide an off-ramp for users looking for more general learning guidance that is off-topic in Stack Overflow Q&A.  Recommending a way for users coming here looking for this to get it without asking off-topic questions seems like a good idea, especially if that supports the site financially.

Comment: My issue, as usual, is with trying to repeatedly, with almost everything they release, pretend it isn't what it is through marketspeak meant to skirt around the fact that it's just more advertising. We aren't fools.

Comment: So, the issue is more with the presentation, not the idea itself? I dunno, I don't find anything misleading or "overly-marketing" about their presentation - in the first sentence, they state that this is advertisements. It's true that the title originally didn't state this, but the vast majority of the downvotes came after the title change, not before. Though, maybe you're finding something to be misleading or offputting that I'm not? Perhaps their general tone of voice? I'm curious how you would have written it differently.

Comment: i mean, i can't really answer for why everyone else downvoted it, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Very well could be mostly people who'd never see these ads anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see Linked or Related questions in the layout image.

Is that just an error in the image or are those removed on questions where ads are shown?

If you plan to remove those, then please reconsider as those are very important for locating related questions.

Also if they are not removed, can you please update the image so we can comment on the positioning.

Comment: I guess the image is from some internal feature-reduced sandbox, the HNQ that are shown in the image are repeated a few times and have the wrong icons. But I agree that for the mockup it would be helpful to know how this interferes with the linked/related lists.

Comment: We don't plan to remove the Linked or Related questions panels (or any other existing feature) as a part of this release. Marijn's right - the screenshot is from a dev version of Stack Overflow. Bits go missing all the time. Unfortunately this means generating a 1:1 copy that is in agreement with how the site looks is quite tricky! But hopefully the provided screenshot still gives you an idea of how it fits into the layout.

Answer (score 5):

> We will base the ads on your *Stack Overflow* browsing history

How exactly are you implementing this?  Are you sending our profile information to the course provider and then they're returning a list of courses to recommend?  Or did they provide you with a list of all available courses, and the Stack Exchange servers are using information they already know to pick which courses to recommend?

In other words, does this new feature involve transferring our personal information to a third party?  I know you said that you don't sell our personal information to third parties but we all know there are lots of types of transfers that don't *technically* count as "selling".

Comment: It's the second one - partners provide us with a course catalog, and (if consenting) we may use your browsing history to determine which courses to serve.

Comment: More or less, our personal information is being used as a value add to the advertiser. By advertising through SO, rather than other means, their ads *in theory* will be more effective because SO is (ab)using our personal data to enhance the product.

Answer (score 4):

Diogenes the Cynic here just with a comment about the wording of the ads.

> Select online courses for you
>
> Helpful courses for you
>
> Popular online courses

The thing is, you aren't suggesting these courses because you genuinely, reasonably believe they will be helpful for me in particular, and you aren't showing them because they're popular. You're showing them because you're getting paid to show them.

It's not like this dishonesty is particularly egregious as far as ad copy goes, but it *is* dishonest. And sure, it's a kind of dishonesty that we know not to take literally, because we're accustomed to advertising being dishonest in this way. But it *is* dishonest.

I think this matters because Stack Overflow more than most other sites depends on the trust and cooperation of its community, and things like this work against that. If you just show adverts written in the advertiser's voice, fine; we understand that you need to show ads to keep the site running. But these ads are written in *Stack Overflow's voice*, saying "we" (SO) decided to show you these links from "our" (SO's) partners because "we" (SO) think they are useful and relevant. So you are training us to expect what *you* say to not be exactly honest, and to tune out and ignore what *you* say. And personally, I don't think that's worth it for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Suggestion**

Part 1: Show the technology courses ads on the tag wikis too.

Part 2: Allow gold tag badge holders to provide feedback about the relevance of specific courses to the corresponding tag based exclusively on the publicly available information (course description, learning goals, demo lessons, bibliography...)

- The images shows the link "Report this add" that apparently is to report the whole widget. This part of the suggestion implies to be able report specific courses.
- The filter should show the most frequently shown courses related to the tag wiki, i.e. show the top 10 courses shown in last 30 days.
- Gold tag badge holders that have a conflict of interest, i.e. they authored a course related to that tag, should mention that on their feedback.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but my only concern would be that the publically available information might be skewed or not enough. Course makers could make the only good park of the course available to gold tag badgers then make the rest complete garbage.

Comment: @MichaelM. I agree that this suggestion will benefit from others ideas. The core idea is to someway help to close the gap between the output of the data scientists models and the perception of the people who very likely really know what is happening on each tag.