# Despite claims to the contrary, course recommendations are not curated based on my interests or relevant to the question

Tags: bug, status-review, advertising

[Stack Overflow is currently serving advertisements for technology courses in the sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422723/we-re-bringing-advertisements-for-technology-courses-to-stack-overflow). On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75479284/how-to-disable-the-transparent-frame-that-is-created-when-you-are-about-to-resiz), I see the following ad in the sidebar:

[image]

In other words, on a question tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) (with no mention of Python anywhere in sight), I see an advertisement for 4 different Python courses. None of these are relevant at all.

The announcement said that the ads would be targeted based on my browsing history if I've opted in to tracking. I have opted in to tracking. I have accepted all cookies, and I have explicitly opted in to use of my on-site activity to show more relevant content in the "Activity data" section of my profile:

[image]

According to the announcement, this should be more than sufficient to ensure that I see targeted advertisements. I have [python*] in my "Ignored Tags" list. I do not ask or answer Python questions. I do not see Python questions on the "Interesting" tab (home page). The site's recommendation engine doesn't think I care about Python questions. It's never shown me one before. (Chances are, as a moderator, my only activity relating to Python questions is deleting them!)

Even if something is not working in my opting in to the targeting of recommendations to me specifically, based on my history, the announcement also says:

> If you opted out of personalized recommendations, we will still recommend courses to you - however, the courses will be based upon other non-personal data, such as the popularity of the course, or the question you’re currently looking at.

As noted above, this specific question is not about Python. There's no [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, and no mention of Python anywhere. There is a strong signal that it is *not* anything about Python, since it is tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

**There's nothing in either my history or this question that should suggest Python might possibly be relevant to my interests. Why is the list of *select*, *curated* online courses *for me* showing Python courses?**

There are at least two bugs here:

1. Targeting is not working, either based on my activity/preferences or based on the question being viewed.
2. The copy in the advertisement dialog is wrong. If it's not targeted to me, it shouldn't say that it is.

The latter is a bug that should be fixed even if the answer is, "Well, there are no courses available on C++, and all of the popular ones are about Python, so these are the only ones we could show to you." If you're not going to [be able to] show me a curated list of courses relevant to my interests and/or what I'm looking at, then don't tell me that you are doing so.

For what it's worth, I've tried refreshing this specific question page multiple times to see if this is just a one-off. It's not. Although the course ads only show up rarely (maybe 1 in 10 page loads or so), every time they do, they contain all Python courses. However, the order is randomized, and it's not always the *same* 4 courses that show up.

Comment: You obviously *hate* Python!!? That’s _it_, we can no longer be friends!!!1!eleven!

Comment: No idea what goals are... but if there are no traces of you knowing Python in the history (unlike let's say gold badge in C++) it makes a lot of sense to offer you Python beginner course vs. C++ beginner one...

Comment: Heh, I did actually consider that angle, @Alexei, but if that were the goal, the description still strikes me as very misleading. I'd rather see it titled "Broaden your skills" or "Want to learn something new?"

Comment: Why did it not send you PHP links?

Comment: Because *nobody* likes PHP, @MartinJames.

Comment: It is about time for you to learn some Python ;) It seems I don't need any courses because I don't see any anywhere.

Comment: Python is one of those languages where I deliberately do not learn anything at all about it. People always want to use it to do automation hack jobs and no way in heck are those going to be assigned to me. "Do you know Python?" -> "NO!" -> "But you can use it to quickly script things!" -> "Exactly!"

Comment: I mean, maybe it thinks it better to show you something you aren't already an expert on

Comment: FWIW i also get python courses from udemy, when viewing non python questions. Python isn't blocked in my case, but it's definitely a tag i avoid. The pluralsite courses were all javascript, which is on par (ignoring the fact that i most certainly don't *need* javascript courses)

Comment:  Ooh, did someone mention PHP? 

Comment: _"my only activity relating to Python questions is deleting them"_ -- if you carry mod duties properly, this may suffice to trigger ads heuristics. There is so much of delete worthy stuff in this tag that just cleaning it up would qualify as high activity in the tag. Although if the ads algo was a tiny little bit smarter it would probably respect your ignored tags

Comment: Maybe they're using the sidebar related questions criteria.