# A proposal on how to improve questions' quality

Tags: discussion, questions

After days of thinking, I found why in Stack Overflow, the experienced members complain about the quality of questions. As a result, they would become reluctant to even open the questions.

I have a proposal regarding the problem.

### Solution

The questions, *first* should queue in the **pre-publish** state. Where each question needs approval from one or a group of reviewers.

**The approval process for publication**:

The question depends on the related tags (C#, Java, Python, Android, etc.) is forwarded to the members who have badges of the related tags for example (Jone Gold in Python, Alex Bronze in C#).

- **IF** the question gets approved from a **Gold** badge member it immediately is **published**
- **IF** the question gets approved from a **Silver** badge member it needs at least **Bronze** or at most **Gold** Badge member
- **IF** the question get approved from a **Bronze** badge member it needs at least 2 **Bronze** member or at most a **Silver** badge member or a **Gold** badge member

Comment: How are questions treated when they use a tag without any badge holders? Python and C# couldn't be more different.  What if none of the badge holders approve or disapprove the question?  How long until the question is published?  What happens if you ask a question and it get's disapproved? How does not publishing questions, help with the quality of the questions being asked, system you describe just seems to require a small subset of experience users to moderate contributions of users who don't care about the quality of their contributions.

Comment: @SecurityHound, `when they use a tag without any badge holders`, they can be published immediately, because affect a small group of a big community (small group of watchers). `What if none of the badge holders approve or disapprove the question` definitely is rejected. `How long until the question is published`  endless period, an automatic notification can sent to the users that review and re-submit the question.

Comment: So, you're essentially proposing a queue that is badge-gated. What exactly is the incentive to perform the review actions there? Because remember that SO gets over 5k questions per day on average. That means that all badge holders (in total) should be ready to review at least that many questions every day.

Comment: @AFarmanbar - So as a gold badge holder to multiple tags, do I get notifications, for every question with that tag every day?  Can I opt out of being notified? What I neither approve or disapprove and just downvote the low quality content?  So if no user approves or dissaves the question it's automatically just rejected?  That seams like a broken frustrating system, which will result in questions being submitted (on the wrong site), asking "where is my question?"

Comment: @VLAZ, I agree with your comment ( `a queue that is badge-gated and all badge holders (in total) should be ready to review `), it's a hard job though. however, there are review actions that are done by community members.

Comment: @AFarmanbar - We already have too few members who perform review actions, you want to increase their workload by ten fold, and not only that limit it to the very users who are typically ANSWERING questions.  So instead of answering a question, the 1% of the population with gold tags, will be busy "publishing" questions?  **How exactly does this help with the quality problem with questions?**

Comment: No, you've not answered. *Why* should people review in that queue? Some 5k odd questions *per day*. And that's on average - on a week day it's not unusual to have 7k questions. You're asking the entire community to buckle down and dive in. And keep doing this *every day*. The review queues are already getting way less action than they should. Heck, I'm not ashamed of admitting, I don't do nearly enough reviews. Because it's a hard job. So, you're asking me, and everybody else, to increase our voluntary workload. With no actual justification why that would be,.

Comment: If this were to come to past, I would just answer questions, and **I WOULD REFUSE to approve ANY AND ALL QUESTIONS** Your proposal just sounds like more work for me, to keep my busy reviewing questions that are so poorly written, they make me want to scream.

Comment: I mean, given my own experience, there's a value argument to be made for people who want to answer questions to want to be involved in a queue like this.  By being able to see questions *before* they're posted, you have the benefit of being first to answer... which we all know is huge value for earning reputation here. Locking it behind tags though would likely not be ideal

Comment: @VLAZ, we have such a mechanism after publish when reviewers go through list of published questions and say is it OK or NOT or NEEDS EDIT. so we can have such mechanism before publish. why not?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't mean that have both of them after & before publishment. remove/replace after publishing review to before publishment review.

Comment: @KevinB I agree, `By being able to see questions before they're posted, you have the benefit of being first to answer`

Comment: @AFarmanbar because the first questions queue is *already* overflowing. There are *right now* 7.8k questions in that queue. FQ items are frequently invalidated if nobody has looked at them in a while (2-3 days, IIRC). So, that's 7.8k items in that queue *right now* with the early booting. Your proposal would have an ever-growing list. Unless you have any way to have uses keep on top of all the incoming questions. And you've yet still to provide a strategy for that. Asking me "but why not" doesn't address the fundamental flow with your suggestions I've outlined three times already.

Comment: @VLAZ, I agree, `the first questions queue is already overflowing`

Comment: by making it the *source* of questions rather than a queue meant to remove already posted questions, it becomes of higher value to people looking to answer questions from new users... since without reviewing said posts wouldn't become actual posts.

Comment: "*I don't mean that have both of them after & before publishment. remove/replace after publishing review to before publishment review.*" never claimed that there would be two. It would be quite silly to do that - it's reviewing the same thing twice. There are 8 review queues total. First Questions queue is just one of them. How do we deal with this new queue which *is mandatory to handle* as well as all the other ones. Replacing FQ still results with a net *huge* extra effort required by reviewers. What's the solution to that?

Comment: More reviewers, obviously. the current queues aren't attracting the numbers we need, so do something different.

Comment: @VLAZ, maybe employing ML to decrease the Queue Length Maybe.

Comment: @AFarmanbar - ML isn’t at that point where it’s reliable enough to be trusted, plus the engineers who are working on AIs, mistakenly think their AIs are alive…In this case the AI uses ML, which is the reason, I bring it up.

Comment: We cannot even trust humans to identify obvious spam, which has been already deleted, I can’t imagine the horrible decisions ML would result in.

Comment: @KevinB that is a valid point though - doing something different. That might be what the doctor ordered to get interest rebooted. I don't think doing yet another review queue is different enough though :)

Answer (score 29):

Not only am I being punished [with *more* review work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418270/1079354), now we get it *twice as hard* on all the [social medias that Stack Overflow Inc. respects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318341/175248) because someone's question was trapped in queue for days.

I cannot stress this enough.

## No thank you.

Comment: I, for one, would love for terrible questions in the [tag:python] tag to be stuck in a queue indefinitely. Even more if the asker has to withdraw the question in order to try again (equivalently, edit to start from scratch). I can understand how proposals like this cause a problem for *unpopular* tags. But how is approving questions, under such a system, any harder than upvoting them? How is that any harder than downvoting them? I already look at multiple questions a day and evaluate them for quality. This is just inverting the polarity of the check, making a whitelist instead of a blacklist.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  In principle I wouldn't mind it either, but the expectation of the ownership of the site is that we're somehow meant to volunteer voluntarily to help clear this backlog, which doesn't sound like something I'm gonna do

Answer (score 15):

I like it. I like it a lot.

I envision a pre-publish queue that will rapidly grow to a size the close vote queue could only have dreamed of in its better years.

And the gold, silver and bronze badgers can finally cleanup the current mess in aisle 42 while keeping the door locked. The tsunami of homework dumps, poorly researched and/or screenshotted questions has come to a halt.

Unless you find give or take 5,000 reviewers that are willing to put in enough reviews, you managed to starve Stack Overflow by letting new users post and then to be never heard from again.

I do agree question quality can use improvements but that (guidance) needs to be done up-front, in social media publications by SE (put that blog to good use), when you visit the site for the first time, when you create an account, when you ask your first few questions, when you get your first down and/or close vote, etc. Until a new users gets the hang of it. Coaching fresh askers so we don't need a queue, pre-publish, first question, low-quality. All busy work for our seasoned users because serious guidance is still lacking, despite some efforts made in that area.