# Staging Ground Workflow: Question Lifecycle

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, staging-ground

Earlier this year, we wrote several posts about various user workflows in the Staging Ground. This post will pull a number of those elements together to focus on the overall question lifecycle, plus we will identify any changes that have been made since the previous posts. The previous posts can be found below:

1. [Staging Ground Workflow: Question Details & Actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416851/staging-ground-workflow-question-details-actions)
2. [Staging Ground Workflow: Listings, Filters, and Notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications)

### Question Lifecycle Summary

Before we get into the lifecycle details, it may help if we lay out the various statuses a post can move through during its time in the Staging Ground.

| Status | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **New** | All posts in the Staging Ground, which at launch is limited to first questions, enter this status after they are created through the Ask Wizard. From this status, posts can be moved to *Major changes*, *Minor edits*, or *Published* by Reviewers or through automation (which will happen if no reviews are performed on the post after a certain number of hours). They can also be moved to *Off-topic* and *Duplicate* statuses (more details below) with sufficient Reviewer votes. Once a post leaves this status, it cannot return to it. |
| **Minor edits** | This status indicates that the post looks good overall, but should receive minor edits before being published. Reviewers can move a post into this status any time they perform a review. Authors can publish from this status (directly or after making any change). If the Author doesn’t publish within a certain number of hours, the post will be published automatically. |
| **Major changes** | This status indicates that the post needs more substantial edits before it is ready to be published, but that it is on-topic for the site and can be salvaged with substantial changes. Reviewers can move a post into this status any time they perform a review. From this status, Authors can only submit the post for re-evaluation and cannot publish it directly. |
| **Re-evaluate** | Posts enter this status if the Author takes an Action on a post that has been in *Major changes*, *Off-topic*, or *Duplicate* status, and chooses to submit it for re-evaluation. Posts in *Off-topic* and *Duplicate* require the Author to perform a significant edit to move into this status. |
| **Published** | Questions can be published by Reviewers from any of the previous states. Once a question is published, it creates a new post on the public site. Unless the post is deleted, this status is permanent within the Staging Ground. The version on the public site will have all the same functionality as posts that don’t go through the Staging Ground. |
| **Off-topic** | If 2 Reviewers vote a post as *Off-topic*, it will enter this status. A significant edit from the Author will send the question to *Re-evaluate*. |
| **Duplicate** | If 2 Reviewers vote a post as *Duplicate*, it will enter this status. A significant edit from the Author will send the question to *Re-evaluate*. |

Some additional rules:

- Other than the *New* status (which a post cannot return to) and the *Published* status (which posts cannot move out of), there’s no limit to how many times posts can change to a different status. If a post requires several Author edits before it is published, it may go through several rounds of re-evaluation before being published.
- We will also maintain the ability for Authors and mods to delete posts – Authors so they can delete posts they do not intend to salvage or no longer need, and mods to help prevent things like inappropriate content, spamming, or other abuse. For example, an Author repeatedly moving a post from *Off-topic* to *Re-evaluate* without an honest effort to improve the question and respond to Reviewer feedback.
- Posts will be flagged as *Inactive* when they are in the *Minor edits* or *Major changes* statuses and the original Author has not taken an Action on the post within 36 hours. By default, *Inactive* posts will be filtered out of the main post listing for the Staging Ground. If Authors return to the post and take an Action on it, the *Inactive* label is removed.

With those statuses outlined, we can now get into the details of how posts move through these statuses. The diagram below helps outline the question lifecycle defined in this post. We’ve made some adjustments to the diagram to help with readability. For instance, we excluded edits, as every edit will either move the post to a different status according to the same workflows defined here, or the post will stay in the same status. We also excluded deleting/undeleting from the chart, though *Deleted* is also a potential end-point for posts – and for visual simplicity, we combined *Off-topic* and *Duplicate*, two different statuses, into a single status in the diagram.

[image: A diagram showing the statuses that a question can move between in the Staging Ground. The statuses included are New, Minor edits, Major changes, Re-evaluate, Published, Off-topic, and Duplicate.]

### Reviewer Actions

Reviewers will be able to perform Actions directly or with an edit on posts in any status except *Published*.

- *Approve and Publish*: This is for questions that can be published as-is. When this Action is taken (by a single Reviewer), the question will be published right away and move the post to the *Published* status.
- *Approve pending Minor edits*: The question looks good, but requires small changes to be made before it can be published. This moves the post to the *Minor edits* status. The UI will require that a comment be left by the Reviewer to explain what edits are needed) when selecting this Action (canned comments can be used here).
- *Require Major changes*: This Action is for on-topic questions that require significant edits and reworking to improve question quality before they can be published, but are still salvageable. The UI will require that a comment be left by the Reviewer to explain what edits are needed when selecting this Action. Canned comments will be provided here for Reviewers to choose from as a starting point for their comment.
- *Vote as off-topic*: For questions that are not appropriate to publish because they are off-topic for the site. Reviewers can vote as off-topic, and this Action opens a modal similar to the existing close vote modal and allows the Reviewer to submit their vote. After two off-topic votes are cast (even if they are for different off-topic reasons), the post will move to the *Off-topic* status.
- *Vote as duplicate*: For questions that are not appropriate for publishing because they are duplicates of existing questions. Reviewers can submit a duplicate vote through this Action similar to the process on the public site today. When two duplicate votes are cast (even if they are for different target posts), the post will move to the *Duplicate* status.
- *Edit post*: This Action allows the Reviewer to edit the post. From the edit page, Reviewers will be asked to take one of three Actions (*Approve and publish*, *Approve pending Minor edits*, or *Require Major changes*) under the assumption that a post worth editing is salvageable and therefore should take a path towards being published. As mentioned in a previous post, this Action is available to users who do not have [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) but still qualify as Reviewers in the Staging Ground.
- *Also add an upvote when published* checkbox: When this is checked (it’s optional) and a review Action is performed, it will note a provisional upvote by the Reviewer on the post. This means that if the post is eventually published, it will receive an upvote right away from the Reviewer. If the Reviewer found the question here to be worthy of an upvote, we want to make it easy for that upvote to be applied once the post is published.

### Author Actions

The Actions an Author can take on a post are highly dependent on the status the post is in:

- Authors can create posts and submit them to the Staging Ground, which will put the post in the *New* status.
- For posts in *New* or *Re-evaluate*, Authors can save edits to the post, but cannot change its status.
- For posts in *Minor edits* or *Major changes*, Authors can edit the post and change its status by publishing from the *Minor edits* status or by submitting for reevaluation from the *Major changes* status.
- For *Off-topic* and *Duplicate* posts, Authors can also make a significant edit to submit the post for re-evaluation.
- As noted above, posts will be automatically flagged as inactive through Author inaction after 36 hours. This is to allow Reviewers to filter out inactive posts, so if the Author returns to an inactive post, they can still take the Actions mentioned here (which will remove the “inactive” label).

#### What’s changed: no closing

The biggest changes to Reviewer Actions since the previous post is the ability to vote that a post is off-topic or a duplicate (in place of the normal “Close post” infrastructure that exists everywhere else). While the Staging Ground is intended to be a place where first-time question Authors receive guidance towards improving the quality of their questions before they go live, we recognize that not all questions are on-topic or can be salvaged.

However, we are avoiding use of the label “Closed” for posts in the Staging Ground. On the main site, “Closed” questions cannot receive new answers. All posts in the Staging Ground are already unable to receive answers, so this label doesn’t apply. Furthermore, new users can be confused by the 'Closed' label and view it as unhelpful and harsh criticism, even when it's applicable given the rules of the site. In place of these, we have 3 statuses in which posts can land: *Require major changes*, *Off-topic*, and *Duplicate*. No post within any of these states will be made public without a Reviewer subsequently approving them, but we are going to do this without labeling them as “Closed”.

A post will require two off-topic or duplicate votes in order to enter either of these statuses. The votes will be cast from the Reviewer Actions section. Once the vote is triggered from the Action list, the workflow for duplicate questions will be the same as the existing workflow on the public site. For off-topic votes, we have reorganized the off-topic reasons to better fit with the intentions of the Staging Ground. We’re including opinion-based closure in the list, and removing options to close questions that need more clarity or focus. Within the Staging Ground, questions in this latter group should be marked as *Require Major changes*, with feedback provided to the Author to help improve the quality of the question.

#### Other changes

We made copy changes to the Reviewer Actions list which you can see below, bringing it in line with the new status options.

[image: New and old Reviewer Action menus. The new menu matches the Reviewer Actions described here.]

In addition, while this is not a change from the previous post, for the initial release, non-moderator Reviewers will no longer be able to vote to delete questions in the Staging Ground; this is a change from public site functionality worth calling out again. For more details on abuse prevention in general, please see [this previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications).

We’ve also added the functionality for an Author to be able to edit a post and save it without moving it to a new status. Previously, after Authors edited a post, we were planning to have them either publish or submit it for re-evaluation (depending on the status it was in before the edit). After some consideration, we decided to allow Authors to save an edit without changing the status of the post. This will give Authors the space to improve their question across multiple edits, while keeping it in a status (*Minor edits* or *Major changes*) where Reviewers are less likely to come across it. It will also keep Reviewers from wasting their time providing feedback where it might not be necessary.

---

We are still in the development phase of this project and while we don’t anticipate more significant changes to  this section, there is still the possibility that some features will change. If you have any questions or feedback about the information in this post, please share it in an answer below.

We have future posts planned that will cover Staging Ground notifications, solicit feedback on canned comments, and describe the launch phases. If there are any significant changes to our plans for the Staging Ground, we will make sure to mention them in future posts.

Comment: Off topic is not a status. Closed is. Please, keep the concepts clear, since off topic for everyone that knows english, means "this is not relevant to the topic at hand", which isn't the same as closed question which means "this question can not receive further answers". If you want, you can use the "on hold" which means the same thing, but doesn't sound definitive.

Comment: Is there an inconsistency here? "Posts will be flagged as Inactive when they are in the **Minor edits** or Major changes statuses and the original Author has not taken an Action on the post within 36 hours. By default, Inactive posts will be filtered out of the main post listing for the Staging Ground. If Authors return to the post and take an Action on it, the Inactive label is removed." In the table at the top, it notes posts that need minor edits will be published, not made inactive, after a period of inactivity

Comment: More on point, wouldn't "Require Minor edits" make more sense than "Approve pending Minor edits"? It would be consistent with the "Require Major edits" action. With the current wording, I have trouble understanding how "Approve minor" ends up in moving a post into the "Minor edits" status.

Comment: @KevinB They'll be marked inactive after 36 hours, then published "a certain number of hours" after that.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I think "Require" is a misnomer if the Author can publish without making any edits.

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Request Minor edits" then, probably? That said, I feel like the UI is sending mixed signals: if it can be published right away, why does it say "the author ... *after an update*"?

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to try and "educate" users considering that 99% of new users just make an account to ask a single question and then disappear from existence...

Comment: Considering new users are already having trouble with the existing process, making the process more complicated seems like a sure-fire way to lose users.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: @Mast I'd be fine with losing users that don't want to put the needed effort in their questions TBH, so even that *could be* a positive thing, but that's just me.

Comment: The biggest problem might be that the staging ground system seems to be slightly different from the main site system, so reviewers will have to learn two sets of reviewing systems/guidelines and might confuse them. Maybe there is a way to unify both a bit more. Maybe also by changing the main site workings.

Comment: Why name one state "minor edits" and another "major changes"...? Why not "minor/major edit" or "minor/major change"?

Answer (score 25):

> *Also add an upvote when published checkbox*: When this is checked (it’s optional) and a review Action is performed, it will note a provisional upvote by the Reviewer on the post. This means that if the post is eventually published, it will receive an upvote right away from the Reviewer. If the Reviewer found the question here to be worthy of an upvote, we want to make it easy for that upvote to be applied once the post is published.

How does this count toward our 40 votes per day limit? If we vote on 40 posts and then review some posts in the staging ground that get approved that same day, and have checked this 'upvote later' box for each of them, will those votes still get applied? Will we be told we have already hit our limit and not be able to check it (even if it doesn't get approved until the next UTC day?)?

> A post will require two [...] duplicate votes in order to enter either of these statuses.

Will a post require two duplicate votes even if the reviewer casting a duplicate close vote has a gold badge in one of the tags used?

Comment: Perhaps even a more general question of is there a limit on the number of staging ground actions per day (like review queues).

Comment: Frankly I don't get why there is a limit on reviews. If people want to clear out the queues and have demonstrated the ability to do so, let them.

Comment: @user4581301 Shog suspected there would be burnout if limits were removed, so he always refused to remove/increase the limits. No one has really made an effort to get them lifted since he left the company AFAIK. Logistically, we could not effectively allow _unlimited_ reviews in _all_ queues without also allowing unlimited voting, both up/down voting and close/reopen voting...

Comment: We plan on having upvotes made through Staging Ground provisional upvotes function the same as upvotes applied directly on the public site. When a question is published the upvote will apply if the vote limit has not already been reached, and it will count towards the limit. Once we see how often provisional upvotes fail to apply upvotes because the limit has already been reached, we can revisit this.

Comment: @user4581301 We live in a day and age where if you put lootboxes in a game, people will spend thousands on it. Per month. The internet is not a safe space if there are no built-in boundaries. The limits need to stay.

Comment: Reasonable counter arguments, but for lootboxes I say the move the limit earlier in the process. I'm not a big fan of folks preying on gambling addictions.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks; any word on the gold badge question?

Comment: @TylerH We're planning to keep the gold badge functionality, so one vote from a gold badge is all that's required.

Comment: @Brendan Excellent, thank you for the update!

Answer (score 20):

> We will also maintain the ability for Authors and mods to delete posts – Authors so they can delete posts they do not intend to salvage or no longer need, and mods to help prevent things like inappropriate content, spamming, or other abuse. For example, **an Author repeatedly moving a post from Off-topic to Re-evaluate without an honest effort to improve the question and respond to Reviewer feedback**.

[emphasis mine]

Questions about the emphasised example:

- How many edits/re-evaluate cycles is considered abusive?
- How is "an honest effort to improve" determined?
- What tools will be provided to detect this?

  - Will an auto-flag be raised? Will users have the ability to flag for moderator attention?
  - Will users have access to a Staging Ground timeline to be able to track the history (or progress) of a post through the Staging Ground?

Comment: At launch, it will be up to mods to determine when behavior is acceptable and when it is abuse or spam and requires moderator action. If we see particular patterns once the Staging Ground launches, we can build guidelines or automation to handle them at that point. Reviewers will be able to flag Staging Ground posts and post timeline will be visible to catch activity like the example provided. More generally, we are currently investigating what tools mods will need to integrate Staging Ground activity into their existing workflows and that includes tools to help surface potential abuse.

Answer (score 19):

> Vote as off-topic: For questions that are not appropriate to publish because they are off-topic for the site. Reviewers can vote as off-topic, and this Action opens a modal similar to the existing close vote modal and allows the Reviewer to submit their vote. After two off-topic votes are cast (even if they are for different off-topic reasons), the post will move to the Off-topic status.

There are several reasons why something is off-topic on this Site. Having just gone through the process of creating a new closure reason there was a **lot** of emphasis on providing adequate guidance for *why* the question is off-topic and what they should do to fix their question.

Some questions are:

- What "off-topic" options will be available?

  - Would this just be limited to our existing community-specific close reasons? Or will there be new off-topic reasons created for the Staging ground?
- What guidance is going to be provided to users about why their question is off-topic and what they should do next?

  - How will that guidance be affected when there is not a consensus of off-topic reason?

Answer (score 13):

> We will also maintain the ability for Authors and mods to delete posts – Authors so they can delete posts they do not intend to salvage or no longer need

Will questions deleted *by the author* in the Staging Ground count towards question bans?

Comment: If the answer to this question is anything other than **absolutely** then it’s absolutely the wrong answer. All contributions submitted should count. There are far to many people who would abuse this new staging ground otherwise

Comment: We are not changing the criteria for how question bans are applied, nor are we treating Staging Ground questions as special cases within the question ban logic.

Answer (score 12):

If a question in the staging ground receives one off-topic and one duplicate vote, will it stay in the staging ground until it receives another vote?

If this is the case, is a single reviewer still able to publish posts with one off-topic and one duplicate vote?

This seems to be implied but I think this should be noted explicitly.

---

The description of the `New` status mentions:

> All posts enter this status after they are created through the Ask Wizard.

Does that only apply for new users or all users. It seems to imply like this applies for all users.

Comment: I think it's for all users and it makes sense that way. This would give experienced users a way to push their question to the SG if they're not sure about its quality by explicitly using the wizard.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide clarity. While all posts within the Staging Ground will have the new status at first, not all posts will enter the Staging Ground. At launch, we plan on sampling from first questions only. We have no firm plans yet, but we have been discussing giving experienced users the option to send their post through the Staging Ground too.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a little confused about the following two statements: <sup>(bold emphasis added by me)</sup>

> [Minor edits:] ... If the Author doesn’t publish within a **certain number of hours**, the post will be **published automatically**.

And:

> Posts will be flagged as *Inactive* when they are in the ***Minor edits*** or *Major changes* statuses and the original Author has not taken an Action on the post within **36 hours**. By default, *Inactive* posts will be filtered out of the main post listing for the Staging Ground. If Authors return to the post and take an Action on it, the *Inactive* label is removed.

1. Do posts in the "Minor edit" status get published, flagged as inactive, or both, if the author doesn't take any action? If it's both, in what order?
2. Does that mean the post will be published in /question but not displayed on the home page?
3. Will the "Inactive" flag be visible in the questions list and/or the question's page itself? And what action is expected from users coming across an inactive question outside the Staging Ground?

Answer (score 11):

How are the posts ordered in this review queue? Oldest first by time of posting? Or oldest first by last author action like editing or submitting for re-evaluation? Or a combination of the two?

When the queue fills up this would run the risk that either new posts are not being reviewed because reviewers are busy handling re-evaluations, or that re-evaluations are not reviewed because reviewers are busy handling new posts.

Is there a concept of Reviewer inaction/aging out of review after a certain number of hours, or can a post stay unreviewed forever (in one of the states that require reviewer intervention)?

In [Staging Ground Workflow: Listings, Filters, Quality Control, and Notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications) the Listings are introduced, which you can sort yourself on activity type and last activity ascending or descending. My current feedback is primarily aimed at the queue part though, i.e., the modal where you choose Submit or Skip and a new review item is loaded. Or is the sort order that you choose in the Listing also used for the queue part? Can you also sort the Listing only by activity, or first by activity and then by status?

Comment: Your filters will apply to the 'queue' of questions when you click 'Submit' or 'Skip', so if you filtered to particular tags you will see questions with those tags. In that submit/skip flow, we will prioritize questions that need Reviewer actions and have some randomization to help avoid Reviewer collision. As for Reviewer inaction, if a question is in the New status for too long without any Reviewer action it will publish automatically. This is to prevent the Asker from having questions in the Staging Ground, where they can't receive answers, indefinitely.

Answer (score 5):

What should I do if I would normally downvote such a question as not showing research or not being useful?

If it is not showing research, should I

- vote for a minor edit asking to add in in research
- vote for a major edit asking to add in in research
- do nothing

If I deem it to be not useful (and have an idea how to make it more useful), should I

- vote for a minor edit asking to increase the usefulness
- vote for a major edit asking to increase the usefulness
- do nothing

Comment: We expect Reviewers will use their discretion, but at a general level major edits replaces some close reasons, like 'Needs more focus', that are available on the public site. So major edits means the post would likely be closed if it were public, and minor edits means there are possible improvements, but the post would remain open. Also, if you are suggesting changes that you think will need another review, then major changes is definitely the right choice. In your second case, if the post is not useful, but could be salvaged with changes, it's a good candidate for major changes.

Comment: @Brendan I read from that that it would all be major edits in my cases here. Minor edits seem to be only for trivial cases then.

Answer (score 5):

This question exclusively talks about edits from the authors. What about edits from others? Are they possible anywhere? Would they affect the status or workflow? When are they encouraged or discouraged?

I think there is a potential to basically make minor edits/streamlinings on the fly instead of waiting for the author to do them.

Comment: Reviewers will be able to edit posts in the Staging Ground as long as they haven't published yet. With the edit, Reviewers can take an action as well, so in the case you identified Reviewers can make changes and publish the post without having to wait for the author.

Comment: Hmm... I've seen some really questionable edits over the years, sometimes by people eager to answer questions they want to answer, but that the author didn't ask. If a Reviewer made such an edit and published, and the Author rolled that edit back (unlikely, to be sure, but it has happened), I'm guessing the question would remain published, as the Staging Ground seems to be one-way.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You mean that edits within the staging ground should only happen by authors or that edits by reviewers should not result in publishing or that a rollback should send question back to the staging ground?

Comment: @Trilarion Yes. :) I'm not sure what the solution is, I just know it's a problem I've seen. It seems like a rollback, by an Author, within a certain period of getting published by a Reviewer, should send the question back to the Staging Ground. It might be too much of an edge case to worry about at this point, though. And maybe that edits by Reviewers should not result in publishing without at least the Author confirming it's good to go. I can definitely see editing in the Staging Ground being good; I edit a lot of posts for grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 3):

I have problems understanding major edits.

> ...we have 3 statuses in which posts can land: Require major changes, Off-topic, and Duplicate.

That seems to indicate that if a question is not clear enough or not focused enough or primarily opinion based or in need of debugging details or not reproducible (all the close reasons except offtopic and duplicate), then I should vote for major change (because only with a major change this question can remain open)?

But

> This status indicates that the post needs more substantial edits before it is ready to be published, but that it is on-topic for the site and can be salvaged with substantial changes.

seems to indicate that questions requiring a major change should indeed be on-topic even without the major edit (so should be clear, focused, non-opinion based, including all debugging details and being reproducible before or be able to be made so).

Or maybe I simply don't understand "...is on-topic for the site and can be salvaged with substantial changes...". Who knows if a question is on-topic for the site and can be salvaged with substantial changes? How can I determine that?

Basically my question is: Does a major edit imply that the question would get immediately closed on the main site without the edit? If the question would get immediately get closed on the main site in the current form should I vote for major edits (and will it be possible to select canned responses as to what the problem is)?

Comment: Even though the terms "off-topic" and "closeable" are often used interchangeably on SE, I took the second quote to mean "on-topic" in the traditional sense, that is, a question which asks about a topic that's within the scope of the site, as defined by the ["On Topic" Help Center page](/help/on-topic). A question which needs more focus may very well be "on-topic" in terms of subject matter, but still be closeable as-written because it's too unfocused, for instance.

Comment: @zcoop98 I mostly stumble over "that can be salvaged with substantial changes". Nobody knows really if that indeed is the case or not. Maybe simply remove that part if it's not adding anything.

Comment: I don't think I agree that "*Nobody knows really if [a question can be salvaged with substantial changes] or not*". If that were truly the case, why do have a "Needs author edit" in Triage queue, rather than just the "flag" option? Maybe I'm making a bad assumption here, but I see the "Major changes" status as basically synonymous to "Needs author edit"; a question that can be edited by the author in some way to be made appropriate. This, in my mind, is distinct from a question that's "unsalvageable"; e.g. total gibberish, or asking about history, which doesn't belong here regardless.

Comment: @zcoop98 If you know how to determine if a post is salvageable then tell me how to it and I will apply it. But I see what you mean with "needs edit" in the triage. It's basically just a rough hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have missed a lot of the post leading up to this one, so forgive me if this has been addressed before, but on a quick glance I never see flags being mentioned. **Will flagging posts be available on the staging grounds?** The obvious use of this are of course the red flags, and the accompanied auto-deletion.

Comment: From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications: "Inappropriate behavior by users is an unfortunate reality that we need to address on the site, and the Staging Ground will not be an exception to this. As such, flagging will be an option on questions and comments, using the same workflow and options that exist today."

Comment: Thanks for the link @Marijn, I'll keep the answer up just incase someone else has the same question.