# Why delete a 'reasonable' (potentially fixable) question within 20 minutes of it being posted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Three high-rep ('trusted') users decided to close and delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76985819/10871073) within about **20 minutes** of it being asked. For those users without the required 10k reputation to see it, here are some screen-shots showing it:

[image]

And here are the comments:

[image]

Now, I can *understand* why it was closed (i.e., lacking a reproducible sample), though I don't necessarily *agree* with that closure – but that's not my main concern, here.

Why did anyone – let alone three established and trusted users – feel the need to delete it so quickly? In my experience/opinion, such rapid deletions should be reserved for posts that are utterly unsalvageable, dangerous, or otherwise 'offensive' (though not necessarily sufficiently so for a red flag).

Deleting this question makes it, effectively, impossible for the OP to edit it to address the reason(s) for closure, and thus submit it for review to be reopened; it also makes it invisible to other users with > 3k but < 10k rep, who might otherwise want to vote to reopen it; if the latter is/was the actual *intent* of the deletion, then it is a case of blatant abuse of the delete privilege.

On the question itself: It *may* not be a stunningly good one but, in my opinion, it has the potential to be answerable and even *useful*. The asker has explained that they cannot reproduce the issue (caused when using a recognized, third-party library<sup>†</sup>) with their 'mimic' version of the class in question, so one would expect anyone who wanted to investigate the problem to have access to that 3<sup>rd</sup>-party library.

Would any of the three delete-voters care to explain why they felt their action was necessary, or even justified? I also welcome comments and opinions about this issue from other users. Maybe I've missed something significant, here, or is this a case of high-rep users getting 'carried away' with their powerful, vote-to-delete privilege?

---

<sup>†</sup> Note: The question, originally, even included the relevant tag ([vst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vst)) for that library – but that was [removed by one of the close/delete voters](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76985819/revisions). I don't know why.

---

This question was closed as a duplicate of [Question deleted in 15 minutes, was it appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422612/10871073) However, I disagree with this closure, for several reasons:

1. Although the "specific-question" aspects of *this* post have been addressed (the referred-to question has been undeleted and reopened), the more general concerns about such rapid deletions are still pertinent; further, I believe that *this* question is better suited as a place for discussing these issues than the suggested duplicate is.
2. That Meta question has no link to the *actual* (main site) question, so it is is difficult to follow the progress thereof (presumably, it has been 'eaten' by the Roomba).
3. In that case, the OP appears to have completely abandoned the question, and no effort appears to have been made to improve it. This is **very different** from the question referred to here, where the OP has fully engaged with the curators and has edited their question accordingly.
4. Because of the points made in (1) and (3), I think this post more eloquently 'challenges' such rapid deletions. Thus, if anything, **this question** should be kept open and the other (maybe) closed against it.

---

Comment: Also worth noting that the question would have been automatically deleted anyway if it wasn't fixed and reopened. Thus there is even less of a reason to delete it *now* as opposed to giving it a few days and having the Roomba take care of it.

Comment: Also related: [How to properly ask a question related to less known SDK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426188)

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah - I was going to mention the Roomba thing in my post but I forgot. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is how the C++ tag normally works, I believe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not in my experience. This behaviour is not (acceptably) normal, nor does it work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat To the extent that this is true, it would probably be good if it did _not_ work like that, though

Comment: @RyanM Yes. While I don't really mind the bad questions being deleted, they (or should I say "we"?) sometimes close good questions too.

Comment: I think there are a few users (in C++ and other tags) who *deliberately* use their delete vote(s) to prevent closed questions being reopened. In fact, there was a stage when the "Reopen Votes" queue was known informally as the "Delete Vote" queue. This is not how things are supposed to work.

Comment: If a question is closed as "Needs debugging details," then it ***must*** be left undeleted sufficiently long for the OP to address that issue. If they fail to do so, then further action may be taken ...

Comment: Meanwhile, I see several high reputation users polluting the C++ tag with answers to questions that should be closed for various reasons. If deletion is a means of combating that behaviour, it’s better to monitor questions for it, and take other kinds of actions against this. Anyway.

Comment: related MSO search query: [`is:q [discussion] [specific-question] [deleted-questions] score:5..`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20%5bdiscussion%5d%20%5bspecific-question%5d%20%5bdeleted-questions%5d%20score%3a5..&searchOn=3). Ex. I distinctly remember [this one from recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423634/11107541)

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact comment to the user that answering close-worthy questions is discouraged with a link to [answer]. If the behaviour is repeated with a clear pattern of ignoring those comments, then I'd flag for moderator attention with a list of those posts' IDs. I also know that some users downvote answers posts that violate Help Center guidelines on answering. up to you how you want to cast your votes. that's an option. though you probably don't want to mix downvoting and commenting.

Comment: Well, even experienced curators make mistakes sometimes. Sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah - I noticed that you cast the third reopen vote. :)

Comment: @cigien Very similar, yes, and the same, basic issue. But I don't really think "duplicate" is appropriate for Meta questions with the `specific-question` tag.

Comment: Anyway, the question has now been undeleted, reopened, edited into far better shape ... and has a non-negative score! All that's missing, really, is an *answer*. :-)

Comment: I recall it being said that a deleted question can't incur more downvotes (thus potentially putting the OP in a deep hole *even if* they improve it). Still... this is not the best UX even if the intention was semi-noble.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, it's not useful to close it as a duplicate (which is why I didn't cast a vote for it), because the linked question didn't solve the problem either. At least to me, the problem is a handful of users aggressively deleting salvageable questions, without giving the OP the chance to salvage them. I don't see that the particular linked question being reopened solves the underlying issue in any way. Unless, of course, the intent of this meta post is to fix just this one instance. Is it the intent to keep coming to Meta each time this happens and get each specific question reopened?

Comment: @cigien The primary intent was focused on the specific question. However, I agree that there is a more general issue and, as you rightly point out, it seems to be mostly limited to a few, high-rep users.

Comment: The questionee has confirmed that they're unable to add a minimal reproducible example, to the question. As such, this question is unanswerable and, indeed, should be closed and deleted. It is unlikely to be of any use, or value. That's the harsh reality. The C++ tag is very sensitive to question quality. I can't speak for the experienced users that originally closed this question, but I'm pretty sure they accurately assessed that this question cannot be fixed, and voted accordingly. I agree.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Why delete *now*? I still see no purpose. If C++ curators are able to see the future, then surely they would also be able to see that their del-vote is wasted.

Comment: Well, others will disagree, and see the purpose in deleting -- to get it off the topic's thread, and hopefully spare a few souls from wasting time opening the question and reading an unanswerable question. The difference is slight, but it's not zero.

Comment: I want to note that you can't _know_ whether the users voting for deletion were the same who also downvoted it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the difference is abuse of moderator privileges, yes

Comment: If you believe that, you are free to promote and push for changes to moderation rules and policy enforcement, that you feel are needed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik please cite the moderation rules and policies that were followed in this case. For me to know what should be changed, of course.

Comment: Rule 1: it takes three votes to close a question. Rule 2: after a question is closed, if it has three downvotes anyone with sufficient privileges can vote for a question to be deleted. Rule 3: three delete votes will delete the question. The End. Feel free to make your argument as to which of these rules should be changed, and why. Keep in mind that it used to be five close votes were needed. This was changed. The historical trend is to make it easier to get rid of low quality questions. I agree.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, that's just the requirement. I want the guidance that says that should be done 20 minutes after posting a question *and* the question is not so bad it has to be removed immediately *and* that the usual chance for reopening should be skipped. Everybody can leave an answer, that's part of the system, but we have guidelines when are answers not an answers. That is the sort of thing I'm after.

Comment: @Sam Those "rules" aren't really the ones that VLAZ was talking about. They are the "effect rules" but what is at issue here are the **guidelines** ... See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) ...

Comment: ... especially this bit: *If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or **for being new**, please flag it for community moderator attention.*

Comment: There is (and never was) anything about this question that would warrant a moderator flag, so why they rush to delete it? Also, note that I parenthesised the "downvote" part of my opening paragraph, because, like @dan1st said, I can't *know* that the downvoters and close/delete voters overlapped. However, I strongly suspect that the delete voters cast downvotes to get the post to the -3 score required for quick deletion.

Comment: @gnat As I said to cigien, although the Q you suggest as a duplicate is (in many ways) the same issue, I would just point out the `specific-question` tag on this one.

Comment: I don't buy this sorry. Title of your question pretends to make a general statement "a... question" instead of "this... question" and all the comments here so far address general statement, not a specific question. As such, this is a duplicate of suggested question which asks about the same general issue

Comment: FWIW "Deleting this question makes it, effectively, impossible for the OP to edit" - this is false. You maybe mistook it for self-deleted questions which indeed can't be edited (for a good reason, but that's a different story). I had one of my questions deleted by 20K votes and it was entirely easy to edit it. (as a side note, I had my questions closed with and without 20K-deletion and I'll pick deletion any time because it makes it so much easier to recover / reopen)

Comment: ... although Cody's comments on that Q (and one of its answers) hit the nail on the head, IMHO. Don't know if he's active just now - or, if so, even interested in this - but a proper *answer* from him (or another moderator) might be a good thing, here. Also note that this question *seems* to be getting a rather better reception than the one you linked, @gnat.

Comment: As for the issue of having a Q undeleted and (potentially) reopened: Yeah, OP (and others) can do that on deleted Qs but, the point is, deletion is a very hard-hitting tool that, I think, was misused here. Most (not all) closed questions should have a chance for review, by both OP and others; the thing is, deleting it makes it far less visible (only the relatively few folks with 10l+ rep can even *see* it. ...

Comment: ... Or, what if a user with (say) 5k, thinks it was closed improperly and would like to cast a reopen vote? What if a low-rep (<3k) user knows how to answer it - on a closed question, they can leave a comment and that may help get it reopened.

Comment: In summary, @gnat, delete votes on questions such as this **should not** be used to somehow hinder/prevent other users (with reopen rights) from disagreeing with the close reason(s).

Comment: you may reason as much as you wish about what is theoretically right but this won't change anything in my personal experience: I don't care if it is "right" or "wrong" but I prefer 20K-deletion of my closed question because to me this makes it much easier to recover and reopen. If you believe that this is a mistake of 20Kers to do so, fine, I want them make such mistakes in my closed questions

Comment: The "guidelines" are, by definition, subjective, @adrian. That's why it takes X votes to close or delete, to establish consensus that the action is appropriate, as per the Holy Guidelines. Therefore, the fact that the action was taken indicates that the Holy Guidelines were met. If you'd like to argue that X votes doesn't establish the guidelines, go ahead and argue that.

Comment: @Sam I have *huge* respect for your contributions (answers, comments and curation) in the C++ tag and, further, I think your "UB" diagnosis (comment on the main-site question itself) may well prove to be accurate. However, I will respectfully disagree with you here: It *may* be that some other user of the VTS library has encountered a similar problem, and has found a fix or workaround.

Comment: That may be true, @adrian but only if the other user made an identical bug with respect to UB, in their code, that had identical consequences. How likely do you think that is? I'm having a hard time remembering when did I come across someone else who made the same exact bug/typo as me, with the same, identical effects.

Comment: What the "rules" allow and what is acceptable use of curation tools aren't necessarily on the same hymn sheet. Those "rules" allow three users to close a question with the reason, "Because chickens only have 5 legs." Doesn't mean it's acceptable for anyone to do so, though.

Comment: If three users happen to vote and enter "because chickens only have 5 legs", independently of each other, that seems to me a pretty good argument that it must be true.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If that is not an MRE I don't know what is. The presence of an external SDK is not grounds for invalidating an MRE. Are you going to force users to include all relevant sections of the Android SDK when they post Android code? Not likely.

I also give it points for investigating some actual bizarre behavior, rather than just a "gimme teh code" question. This should never have been closed.

Comment: Also, interesting to note the (probable) Meta-effect, here, working in a **net positive** way. The Q has accrued 16 upvotes since I raised this issue, here (along with a few extra downvotes, though). Meta.SO isn't necessarily as "toxic" as some would have us believe. (Harsh - maybe - but that's kinda its *raison d'être*.)

Comment: Oh cripes. I just read the comments under the question more closely. Seems like the error the OP is likely running into directly has to do with how the SDK was built/linked. And OP has not included how they built that library. Well, this is why its worth really reading carefully. I'll leave this up, but I think I was wrong here.

Comment: I think the OP *has* given info on what version of the SDK is being used and (to an extent) how it was built. They certainly addressed the comment from Hans (or, at least, tried to). As for the 32/64 bit mix-up: That would almost certainly cause a linker error with the MSVC build tools.

Comment: @AdrianMole It's a C++ question. Meta effect is always positive for C, C++, Haskell, Rust, etc. questions.

Comment: This, plus - even if a question is missing an MRE, but is part-way there, or seems otherwise-legit and has just been asked by a newbie - I prefer to comment about how to improve the question, saying that if they don't do that, it might get closed and/or downvoted.

Comment: @einpoklum i agree, but typically don't include a warning... as that can result in the user feeling like their question is being held hostage. with or without the warning, the consequences are the same.

Comment: @KevinB: It's true that the advice may sound like "I'll make you an offer you can't refuse", but - (1.) they know the commenter is not the person deciding the fate of their question and (2.) better to be held hostage than to just be shot...

Comment: @einpoklum Re _"I prefer to comment about how to improve the question"_, well said! I see that an obnoxious comment (_"...Why do you think we will be able to?..."_) in the OP's screen shot of comments has thankfully been removed, but posting condescending, rhetorical questions in comments remains a problem on SO. High rep users doing that, who have absolutely no interest in helping the user or answering the question, should be ashamed. And they drive new SO users away - whatever happened to _"be nice"_?

Comment: @AdrianMole Upvoting can still happen for all the wrong reasons. The meta effect is often described as an acceleration of normal voting activity due to the spotlight, but normal voting activity does not have a meta post acting as a guiding force and a funnel to get a pretty smallish and unchanging group of people to descend upon it so that is not a wholly honest description.

Comment: @skomisa: TBH, I would much rather get a snide comment, but which actually indicates what I can do to get an answer, than a silent downvote, which is "polite" and CoC-compliant but doesn't help me do better. Although I suppose that might not be the universal preference.

Comment: @einpoklum It's good that you have a thick skin, but new posters may not. I don't know how much harm is done by rude and condescending comments (that's impossible to quantify), but it surely deters some users from posting on SO to some extent. And apart from that, it's ugly, unproductive and unprofessional.

Comment: @skomisa: Well, I want to challenge that claim, or rather - challenge the claim that it's "ugly, unproductive and unprofessional" _relative to a silent downvote_. Let me start with **ugliness**: Being downvoted is somewhat hurtful, especially to new users, for whom it is an effort to manage to form, phrase and publish a question; being criticized in a condescending way is also somewhat hurtful. But I find that the effect of just hurting via a downvote without giving cause is much uglier than than the condescension. The condescending critic cares enough to take the time to engage with you /...

Comment: ... rather than perform a hit-and-run. Regarding **productiveness** - here I believe it is obvious that the condescending comment about what's wrong with one's question is more productive than just the downvote. Finally, regarding **professionalism** - I claim that downvotes without comments are about as unprofessional as condescending/abusive comments. So in the overall balance, the hurtful but also actionable comment is better, IMO, than the silent downvote.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm afraid that is just the problem of people taking downvotes too damn personally. Rejection is a standard occurrence in many areas of society, yet downvotes are somehow different? It also doesn't make a great argument for why the voters should expose themselves to abuse by commenting every time they downvote. Anyways, this is a digression. Let's take it elsewhere.