# Question is not viewed for about 8 hours

Tags: support, views, staging-ground

I guess I was chosen to be a part of testing Staging Ground.

But my question has not been viewed for moderation for about 8 hours.

I'd be happy to test new features, but I'd like to have an answer to my question much more.

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/74840469)

Comment: It's a particularly low traffic time of the year (many people are travelling, celebrating various holidays, etc.) _and_ posted on a weekend (which normally has less traffic) _and_ there's a very small group of users with access to the beta test of Staging Ground. It's a bit unfortunate, but some wait time is likely to be expected in this case.

Comment: Only users with access to the Staging Ground (askers, moderators, and beta reviewers) will be able to view the linked question. It's not broken, access is just highly limited at this time.

Comment: I don't think the question should have been posted yet. It lacks proper title.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a help desk, there is no guarantee that you would get an answer in N hours, etc. 8 hours isn't that long.

Comment: "but I'd like to have an answer to my question much more" - so keep searching yourself.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat my two previous questions were answered in about one hour, so I was expecting that timing gap.

Comment: The comments may seem negative, but they are fair: one cannot expect questions on the staging ground to be attended in a timely manner (as this site is not a helpdesk), so most folks think you should have had more patience.

Comment: @NickZakharov you have to understand that all of the content generation / curation (posting questions / answers, reviewing, flagging etc.) is majorly done by **volunteers**. Given that there are multiple people posting questions, asking to move up in the queue is pretty rude. Giving justification that your previous questions were answered in about an hour doesn't make sense, if you see your published question was asked about 18 hours ago yet there is no answer.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (question graduated from SG beta)

---

Yes, your question was chosen for the Staging Ground Beta. Please be patient, in case none of the beta-reviewers review your question in the established limit time it will automatically moved to the public page.

NOTE: AFAIK the limit time has not publicly disclosed.

Related:

- [Staging Ground Workflow: Question Lifecycle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419746/1595451)
- [Help needed: a call for volunteer reviewers for the Staging Ground beta test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421718/1595451)

Comment: As an indication a range 'The inactivity period is still to be decided, and will most likely be either 24 or 48 hours.' was given in [Staging Ground Workflow: Listings, Filters, Quality Control, and Notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications)

Comment: The time limit is currently 24 hours (From looking at some of the automatically published posts).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with what many others have already said. The *helpers* here are *volunteers* doing this on their *free* time. Your urgency is not our urgency- whether inside or outside of Staging Grounds.

I *personally* am here to contribute to a repository of information that holds long-term value to a wide audience. That is not the same as being here to help specifically you. Some helpers like helping individuals for the individual's sake. That's up to personal taste. Not everyone is like that. In fact- Stack Exchange *is* (supposed to be) a repository of information that holds long-term value to a wide audience- not a help desk.

That being said, I am helping out as a reviewer for the Staging Ground testing and have been helping many individuals improve their posts. **Be patient!** Something similar to [help/no-one-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) can be said for waiting for reviews in Staging Grounds. If you want to save time in Staging Grounds, then focus your efforts on writing a good question post, which will save you some back-and-forth of iterating on feedback. If you want help on how to do that by yourself, here are the links that I most frequently find myself asking askers to read and implement guidance from:

- [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [images-of-text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541)
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)
- ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541)